# Bold , italic (and sans-serif) math symbols

Tags: math-mode, bold, characters, italic, sans-serif

I would like to implement the suggestions in the [TUGboat 30:3, 2009](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96vieth.pdf) about the upright/italic and bold/normal in scalars, vectors and tensors. All this is about math.

I use this font:

```
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
```

For vectors, I always used `\vec`, so I just redefined it like so:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
```

Now they are bold and italic, just like I want them. Is that even the correct way to do this?

How can I get characters in bold, italic and sans-serif?

I *almost* got it with this, they are just upright and not italic:

```
\newcommand{\tens}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathsf{#1}}}
```

Comment: It's not clear, but are you looking for: `\mathbf` `\mathit` \nathsf`

Comment: `\mathbf` makes the font upright. And I cannot combine `\mathsf` and `\mathbb`.

Comment: Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24035/14100

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cleanest way is to define a new math alphabet:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{bx}{n}
```

and then

```
\newcommand{\tens}[1]{\mathbfsf{#1}}
```

If you want italic bold sans serif, just change the first declaration into

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{bx}{sl}
```

but keep in mind that the OT1 encoded Computer Modern Sans fonts don't have slanted bold face, so also

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

or

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

is required.

---

You should also consider using `\bm` of the `bm` package instead of `\boldsymbol`, so that `\bm{\mathsf{T}}` would be equivalent to the `\mathbfsf{T}` with the first declaration. However there is no predefined sans serif italic math alphabet. So, if you need also sans serif italic, a more economic setting would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{bx}{sl}

\newcommand{\tens}[1]{\bm{\mathsfit{#1}}}

\begin{document}
$\tens{T}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a brace `}` missing at the end of the `\newcommand`-line. I cannot edit it since it is just a single char.

Comment: The latter works great, even with greek letters. Thank you!

Comment: No joy with \Gamma: `$\tens{\Gamma}$` gives a bold backtick-like something (both solutions, texlive 2021).