# pgfplots - How to get the y axis in sans serif

Tags: fonts, pgfplots, sans-serif

I made a coordinate system with pgfplots. Now I want the font to be in sans serif, so I tried the command `\sffamily` after document start (just like in the example). With this everything is in sans serif but the y-axis labels. I tried `\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]` as well as `\pgfplotsset{ticklabel style = {font=\sffamily},
y axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily},
}` but all of this comes to the same result shown underneath the code.

Does anybody know how to get the font of the y axis in sans serif, too?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5,xmax=105,
    ymin=0,ymax=12,
    x dir=reverse,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line*=top,
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    extra x tick labels={{0},{10},{20},{30},{40},{50},{60},{70},{80},{90},{100}},
    every x tick/.style={},
    xlabel=Palmfett / Gew.\%,
    xlabel style={at={(0.5,1.225)}},
    ]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5 ,xmax=105,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    extra x tick labels={{0},{10},{20},{30},{40},{50},{60},{70},{80},{90},{100}},
    extra x tick style={grid=major},
    every x tick/.style={},
    xlabel=Bienenwachs / Gew.\%,
    ylabel=Martenshärte / N/mm$^2$
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to change the font of certain elements then you can define them so

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5,xmax=105,
    ymin=0,ymax=12,
    x dir=reverse,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line*=top,
    xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    yticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    xlabel=Palmfett / Gew.\%,
    xlabel style={at={(0.5,1.225)}},
    ]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5 ,xmax=105,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    yticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    xlabel=Bienenwachs / Gew.\%,
    ylabel=Martenshärte / N/mm$^2$
    ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This will keep the axis labels untouched but the tikc labels in sans-serif without going through the extra label declarations.

Answer (score 3):

The tick labels are type set in math mode i.e., `$0$` etc. So the `\sffamily` is not respected there.  You can either force `\sffamily` in math mode as per the answers [to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24035/11232) or make `ytick=\empty` as you did for `xtick`s and use `extra y tick`s. Also, it is enough to pass `[font=\sffamily]` to `tikzpicture` to change the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{cmbright}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}%,tick label style={font=\sffamily},}
\begin{document}
%\sffamily 

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5,xmax=105,
    ymin=0,ymax=12,
    x dir=reverse,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line*=top,
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    extra x tick labels={{0},{10},{20},{30},{40},{50},{60},{70},{80},{90},{100}},
    ytick=\empty,
    extra y ticks={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
    extra y tick labels={{0},{2},{4},{6},{8},{10},{12}},
    every x tick/.style={},
    xlabel=Palmfett / Gew.\%,
    xlabel style={at={(0.5,1.225)}},
    ]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    width=14cm,
    height=7cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5 ,xmax=105,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    axis y line*=left,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    xtick=\empty,
    extra x ticks={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    extra x tick labels={{0},{10},{20},{30},{40},{50},{60},{70},{80},{90},{100}},
    extra x tick style={grid=major},
    ytick=\empty,
    extra y ticks={0,2,4,6,8,10,12},
    extra y tick labels={{0},{2},{4},{6},{8},{10},{12}},
    every x tick/.style={},
    xlabel=Bienenwachs / Gew.\%,
    ylabel=Martenshärte / N/mm$^2$
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]