# pgfplots changing font of data labels to sans-serif / MyriadPro

Tags: pgfplots, fonts, sans-serif

I am making bar charts using pgfplots and I would like to change the font of the "data labels" to a sans-serif font (preferably Myriad Pro), but I'm having no luck. I am compiling with `XeLaTeX`

I've tried to use the package `mathastext` as suggested here ([pgfplots - How to get the y axis in sans serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274177/pgfplots-how-to-get-the-y-axis-in-sans-serif)), but my data labels are displayed as serif.

Here is a minimum working example:
**Any thoughts on how to change the data labels to sans-serif?** 
Thank you!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setromanfont{Myriad Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic y coords={
    {Disability},
    {Death},
    {Congenital Anomaly}
}, % name of categorical data
ytick=data,
]
\addplot[
xbar, 
fill={black},  
nodes near coords, % adds data labels on each bar
nodes near coords align={horizontal}, % aligns data labels on each bar
nodes near coords style={font=\large}
] coordinates {
    (10,{Congenital Anomaly})
    (1199,{Death})
    (285,{Disability})
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image: serif data labels]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need extra packages for this. The reason why numbers are still serif is because they are typeset in math mode i.e. every number has `$...$` around them because that's what you generally want and pgfplots is trying to help you. However you can turn off this behavior by using `assume math mode` for the number printing such that it assumes that it is already inside math mode and prints the number as is. Example without any fonts (notice I don't redefine any macro and neither should you)

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic y coords={
    {Disability},
    {Death},
    {Congenital Anomaly}
}, % name of categorical data
ytick=data,
tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode}
]
\addplot[
xbar, 
fill={black},  
nodes near coords, % adds data labels on each bar
nodes near coords align={horizontal}, % aligns data labels on each bar
nodes near coords style={font=\large,/pgf/number format/assume math mode}
] coordinates {
    (10,{Congenital Anomaly})
    (1199,{Death})
    (285,{Disability})
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Same should also be applied to tick labels too but that's a minor addition

[image]