# Change font of axis and nodes near chords on plot to match rest of document

Tags: fonts, fontsize, plot

I would like to make all symbols, numbers, letters etc to match the font of the rest of my document. Currently, the X-axis and title has the correct font. But the y axis and the numbers for "nodes near chords" do not. How do I do this?

This is how it currently looks like with my code:
https://gyazo.com/05ab769479252a77e78360ea037ad70d

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[landscape, a4paper, bottom=0.0in, margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


%Customization
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot
\usepgfplotslibrary{
  units, % Allows to enter the units nicely
  groupplots
}



\pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\definecolor{customgreen}{RGB}{21,155,151}
\definecolor{custompink}{RGB}{230,55,148}
\definecolor{customlightblue}{RGB}{207,210,235}
\definecolor{customlighterblue}{RGB}{232,234,245}
\definecolor{custombrown}{RGB}{194,181,155}



\title{test}
\author{sinasohi}
\date{January 2017}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\include{Page1}
\include{Page2}
\include{Page3}
\include{Page4}
\include{Page5}

\end{document}
```

Page3 code:

```
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval    & a     & b     \\
    K74         & 32.9  & 27.5  \\
    K76         & 23.5  & 22.5  \\
    K75         & 25.7  & 25.0  \\
    K77         & 22.3  & 30    \\
    K89-90      & 30.6  & 30    \\
    K92         & 19.3  & 15    \\
    }\mydata

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval        & a     & b     \\
    K78             & 18.8  & 20  \\
    K85, K86, K87   & 66.3  & 60  \\
    }\yourdata

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={group size=2 by 1},
            legend style={at={(0.5,1)}, text width=6em, text height=1.5ex, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            ybar,
            /tikz/bar width=.6cm,            
            xtick=data,
            ymin=0, %ymax=40,
            ,height=10cm,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={color=black, font=\footnotesize}            
        ]

\nextgroupplot[
   title=\textbf{Kardiovaskulære diagnoser},
   width=.55\textwidth,
   symbolic x coords={K74,K76,K75,K77,K89-90,K92},
   ymax=40
]
        \addplot[red!20!customgreen,fill=customgreen!80!white] table[x=interval,y=a]{\mydata};
        \addplot[red!20!custompink,fill=custompink!80!white] table[x=interval,y=b]{\mydata};
        \legend{Klinik 12345, Landsrapport}

\nextgroupplot[
    symbolic x coords={K78, {K85, K86, K87}},
    width=.3\textwidth,
    enlarge x limits=0.7,
    title=\textbf{Yderligere diagnoser},
    ymax=80,
    /tikz/bar width=.7cm,
    ]

        \addplot[red!20!customgreen,fill=customgreen!80!white] table[x=interval,y=a]{\yourdata};
        \addplot[red!20!custompink,fill=custompink!80!white] table[x=interval,y=b]{\yourdata};
        \legend{Klinik 12345, Landsrapport}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

does not change the font used for math mode. Use e.g. (in addition to the above line)

```
\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}
```

For further solutions see [Typeset mathematical symbols also in sans serif font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/typeset-mathematical-symbols-also-in-sans-serif-font).