# How do I use Arial in math mode alongside the default font settings?

Tags: math-mode

I want some symbols/text in math mode to be Arial? This cannot ve done by changing the settings for various kinds of text in math mode like the default italic text or the default bold text. Put another way, I want something like `\arial{text}` the same there is stuff like `\mathbb{text}` and `\mathcal{text}`. How do I do this?

Comment: You could have a look at the `newtxsf` package and the answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/typeset-mathematical-symbols-also-in-sans-serif-font

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX anyways!

Comment: @JasperHabicht Nope. That question's answers involve changing the particular defaults for whatever kind of text is used in math mode (i.e., italic, bold, non-italic, etc.). That is not what I want.

Comment: @TeXnician Please unlock this question as I have edited such that it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: @Troy Please unlock this question as I have edited such that it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: @Skillmon Please unlock this question as I have edited such that it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Please unlock this question as I have edited such that it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Please unlock this question as I have edited such that it is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: Please provide an MWE which shows any font configuration you have for text/maths, any symbols packages you are loading etc. If your MWE does not make it obvious, please specify your compiler also. Question: what do you mean by Arial? Arial? Or a clone? You also need to tell us the scope of your request: what exactly do you want to access in this way? Note that TeX is limited to 16 maths fonts. Depending on your current configuration, you may need to prioritise what you want to access in Arial. Or do you just want to access Arial/clone *text*, rather than maths symbols etc.? That's more open.

Comment: @cfr What is an "MWE"? By "Arial" I mean the font that looks like Arial or whatever "clone" it is that most LaTeX environments use as "Arial". What do you mean TeX is limited to 16 math fonts? As to your last question, I don't understand the difference. I've seen papers whose equations have Times New Roman and Arial in them.

Comment: @Melab An MWE is a Minimal Working Example: see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=1|0.0000 for help making one. I don't know anybody has done a survey re. clone popularity. LaTeX can also use Arial, depending on your compiler and if you have the font, of course. TeX can't use more than 16 maths fonts in a document. The number of text fonts isn't similarly limited. Hence, it matters a lot just what you need access to and how many maths fonts you're using already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use math mode and siunitx with arial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469775/how-to-use-math-mode-and-siunitx-with-arial)

Comment: Hope `sansmath.sty` may helps you...

Answer (score 2):

With `unicode-math`, you can:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\matharial}{Arial}[
   Ligatures={Common, Tex} ,
   Scale = MatchLowercase ]
```

In legacy NFSS, you can load `uarial` or `winfonts` along with `amsmath` and then select the font inside a `\text` command, e.g.

```
\newcommand\matharial[1]{\text{\normalfont\itshape\fontfamily{arial}\selectfont #1}}
```