# How to use math mode and siunitx with arial

Tags: math-mode, fonts, siunitx

I have to use arial within the whole document. My code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            uarial,%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23957/how-to-set-font-to-arial-throughout-the-entire-document/23961#23961
            amsmath,
            eurosym
           }
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23957/how-to-set-font-to-arial-throughout-the-entire-document/23961#23961
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110972/eurosym-seems-to-not-be-working/110979?r=SearchResults#110979
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi{
  \fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}
\begin{document}

  Text.
  \begin{align}
    K & = A_0 + \sum\limits_{t = 1}^{T} A_t ( 1 + i )^{-t} \text{, mit $T = 3$ und } i = \SI{4}{\percent} = \frac{4}{100} \Rightarrow\\
      & = \left( - 500 + \ldots + \frac{200}{1{,}04^3}\right) \EUR{1000}
  \end{align}
  Text.

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

My observation:

1. If I have `\text{}` in a math mode than it appears sans serif.
2. `siunitx` content appears sans serif too, even numbers.
3. But all other content appears in serif.

Than I have a mixture of sans serif and serif. I don't have the experience in this area and don't know how it should be. For me it looks inconsistently. I found a lot of information here ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/typeset-mathematical-symbols-also-in-sans-serif-font), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41497/how-to-typeset-some-text-including-math-content-in-sans-serif) and [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33165/make-mathfont-respect-the-surrounding-family)) and don't know what I should to use.

Which is the usually way?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: I don't recommend uarial: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309120/2388

Comment: Back in 2012 some work (need to translate using url from German) was done by Günter Milde with a kudos to @UlrikeFischer see http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/ . lots of nice tables such as http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/Matheschriften/matheschriften.html with sources at http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/Matheschriften/?C=M;O=A

Comment: Do you really *have* to use Arial? Arial is *not* a math font, which means you get sub-optimal (and sometimes ugly) math formulas by substituting math fonts with Arial. If your goal is to have sans-serif for your whole document, why not consider using Fira Go as your text and Fira Math as your math? See the [home page](https://github.com/firamath/firamath) of Fira Math for showcase. (Unrelated note: Use `\cdots` instead of `\ldots`, `;-)`)

Comment: Hello @Ruixi Zhang! Yes I have to use arial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The Modern Way

I personally recommend you use `unicode-math` on LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX when you can, and the legacy toolchain when you have to.  You’ll get more symbols with more consistency than any combination of legacy packages could give you, it’ll be simpler, and you’ll even be able to copy and paste from the PDF.

It also allows you to use any system font in LaTeX, including Arial from the MS core fonts.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{babel}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX }
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Andale Mono}
\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}
\setmathfont[range=up]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Arial Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Arial Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Arial Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=tt]{Andale Mono}

\newcommand\EUR[1]{\mbox{#1\,\texteuro}}

\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
  Text.
  \begin{align}
    K & = A_0 + \sum\limits_{t = 1}^{T} A_t ( 1 + i )^{-t} \text{, mit $T = 3$ und } i = \SI{4}{\%} = \frac{4}{100} \Rightarrow\\
      & = \left( - 500 + \ldots + \frac{200}{1{,}04^3}\right) \EUR{1000}
  \end{align}
  Text.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: MS Arial sample]

## With Modest Changes

This version adapts your MCVE with the following adjustments: It explicitly sets up `textcomp` to use the Arial version of the Euro symbol (and declares `\EUR` for compatibility), sets the math symbols to the sans-serif version of newtx, and sets the math letters to the text font with `mathastext`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            newtxsf,
            uarial,%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23957/how-to-set-font-to-arial-throughout-the-entire-document/23961#23961
            textcomp,
            amsmath
           }
%from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23957/how-to-set-font-to-arial-throughout-the-entire-document/23961#23961
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\newcommand\EUR[1]{\mbox{#1\,\texteuro}}

\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
  Text.
  \begin{align}
    K & = A_0 + \sum\limits_{t = 1}^{T} A_t ( 1 + i )^{-t} \text{, mit $T = 3$ und } i = \SI{4}{\%} = \frac{4}{100} \Rightarrow\\
      & = \left( - 500 + \ldots + \frac{200}{1{,}04^3}\right) \EUR{1000}
  \end{align}
  Text.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: URW Arial sample]

It is also possible to use Microsoft’s version of Arial in PDFTeX through the `winfonts` package.  Use the command `\fontfamily{arial}\selectfont`, or redefine `\familydefault` and perhaps `\sfdefault`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            newtxsf,
            winfonts,
            textcomp,
            amsmath
           }

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{arial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\newcommand\EUR[1]{\mbox{#1\,\texteuro}}

\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
  Text.
  \begin{align}
    K & = A_0 + \sum\limits_{t = 1}^{T} A_t ( 1 + i )^{-t} \text{, mit $T = 3$ und } i = \SI{4}{\%} = \frac{4}{100} \Rightarrow\\
      & = \left( - 500 + \ldots + \frac{200}{1{,}04^3}\right) \EUR{1000}
  \end{align}
  Text.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arial font sample]

Including the `winfonts` package isn’t strictly necessary here, but at least requiring it tells the user what package needs to be installed.

Comment: You may want to mention that, as a non-math font, Arial does *not* have a proper “math table”, and thus the math formulas will be sub-optimal. The `t` touching `=` in the subscript of the `\sum`, the `i` touching `)` in the summand, etc.

Comment: Also, by issuing `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}` you are effectively scaling Arial against Latin Modern, which is probably undesired (as the “main” font, there is no need to be scaled). For this reason, you may want to add `\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1}` as well. See the last paragraph before Section 6.3 in the `fontspec` manual.

Comment: @RuixiZhang The `[Scale=1.0]` suggestion is good, and I might edit it in. I usually do have something like that.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Unfortunately, the only sans-serif Unicode math font currently available is Fira Math, which is a work in progress. My choice of a font with wide equals signs as the backup made that issue worse.

Comment: Hello @Davislor! Thank you for your answer! Like I understood the above example is for `LuaLaTex` or `XeLaTeX` only. The below example works with `pdfLaTeX` too? Another (maybe not smart) question: As you wrote (see [also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370280)) is the default since 2018, why do you have it in the preamble?

Comment: @Su-47 Yes, you’re right about which TeX engines to use.

Comment: @Su-47 I add `inputenc` to all my PDFTeX examples here so that they will still work in older installations. In this case, it’s not needed: I don’t actually use any non-ASCII input characters.

Comment: Hello @Davislor! Thank you for your comments! One last thing: Have one the chance to use arial instead of uarial without to move to `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`? If yes, could you please add a third example showing it? Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: @Su-47 Yes, the `winfonts` package lets you do that.

Comment: Hello @Davislor! Thank you for the third example and the comments! Next task: I use `MiKTeX` and it doesn't contain `winfonts`. Is there a way to get it working? Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: @Su-47 If you are on Windows, or installed MS Office. and already own the fonts, the instructions are here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/winfonts  (But remember, these fonts are copyrighted.) You might also want https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/ which contains uarial.