# How to change to Arial for all fonts including math?

Tags: fonts

I want to change my all fonts - text and math - to Arial if possible.  I tried adding

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

but the math fonts don't look good.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you **have to** use Arial? If you only need a sans serif font, try Fira and Fira Math: https://ctan.org/pkg/firamath

Comment: Not necessarily.  I like it though, so any close derivative is appreciated.  Anyway, how would I deploy Fira and Fira Math?

Comment: there is no arial math font.

Comment: Is there a math font that is known to go well with Ariel?

Comment: Prince Eric goes well with Ariel. Here is a list of math fonts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available and another: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use math mode and siunitx with arial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469775/how-to-use-math-mode-and-siunitx-with-arial)