How to globally configure the size and position of subscripts and superscripts?
I am working on designing a template for a mathematics textbook, aiming to achieve the style or appearance shown in the following image:

However, my current output looks like this:

Observed issues:

The subscripts and superscripts are larger compared to the desired
style.

The position of the subscripts and superscripts is different; hey are too close to the variable.


 

The position of the subscripts and superscripts in parentheses is too far apart.

The height of the parentheses is smaller compared to the original image.


 
How can I globally configure the subscripts and superscripts in LaTeX to resolve these issues?
In my configuration, I am using the fontspec package with unicode-math to set up the font. I have tried using DeclareMathSizes, but it is not compatible with unicode-math.
Can any unsung hero help me address these problems?
I apologize in advance for any inconvenience; I am new to LaTeX, and I appreciate your attention.
Thank you!
Below, I show my configuration:
% I'm working with XeLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math} %math-style=ISO es para que 
% \defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX }

% Configura las fuentes para el texto
\setmainfont{CronosPro-Lt.otf} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469775/how-to-use-math-mode-and-siunitx-with-arial

% Configura la fuente matemática principal
\setmathfont{KPMATH-LIGHT.OTF}

% Configuración para conjuntos específicos
\setmathfont{MathematicalPiLTStd} [range=it/{greek,Greek}, Scale=MatchLowercase, FakeSlant=0.2, UprightFeatures={FakeStretch=0.9}]    % Letras griegas
\setmathfont[range=it/{latin,Latin}]{CronosPro-LtIt.otf} % Letras latinas
\setmathfont[range=up/num]{CronosPro-Lt.otf}        % Números

\begin{document}
\textbf{Halla el valor de $k$ si las raíces de $(2k+3)x^2-(k-1)x+1=0$ son iguales.}

Identificamos los coeficientes: $a = 2k + 3$, $b = -(k - 1) = 1 - k$, $c = 1$.

Las raíces deben ser iguales: $x_1 = x_2$ \quad (1)

Aplicando las propiedades y la igualdad (1) obtenemos:

\[
x_1 + x_2 = -\frac{1 - k}{2k + 3} \quad \xrightarrow{Por (1)} \quad x_1 + x_1 = -\frac{1 - k}{2k + 3} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad 2x_1 = \frac{k - 1}{2k + 3} \quad (2)
\]
 
\[
x_1 \cdot x_2 = \frac{1}{2k + 3}  \quad \xrightarrow{Por (1)}  \quad x_1^2 = \frac{1}{2k + 3} \quad (3)
\]

De las igualdades (2) y (3) resulta la ecuación: \[\left(\frac{k - 1}{2(2k + 3)}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2k + 3} \quad (4)\]

Resolvemos la ecuación (4) y obtenemos dos valores para $k$:

\[
\frac{(k - 1)^2}{4(2k + 3)^2} = \frac{1}{2k + 3} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad k^2 - 2k + 1 = 4(2k + 3) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad k^2 - 10k - 11 = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow
\]
\[
\Longrightarrow(k - 11)(k + 1) = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad k_1 = 11 \quad \text{y} \quad k_2 = -1
\]
\end{document}


welcome! please add your document class to your code so it potentially compiles. I removed latex3 as that doesn't seem relevant and added some maths-specific tags. you've tagged this both xetex and luatex, so it isn't clear which you are using. some of the spacing issues are a result of substituting bits of the maths font pick-and-mix style. spacing with unicode-math depends heavily on the maths font and substituting bits and pieces undermines that process. try e.g. \Bigg( instead of \left(. off-topic: don't hard code things like equation numbers. use proper markup instead.

When you use a text font in math, you cannot expect spacing to be "correct". Also, it looks as if the text font is in general slightly smaller than the symbols from the math font. That can explain why the parenthesis around 2k+3 is larger in your case. If you mix the fonts, you should probably scale as well.

You can use $\displaystyle ...$ to get the subscrpts etc. to be the same as in \[ ... \].  Or use \[\textstyle ... \] to match $ ... $.

Thank you very much, everyone. Are you saying that there is no way to globally configure and control the size, position, etc.? Does that mean I have to adjust it manually for each equation?

well, the best thing would be to use a maths font for maths rather than mixing a text font. ;)
