# Including python matplotlib plots in LaTeX documents and inheriting document font properties

Tags: pgfplots, matplotlib

I am trying to get a standardised method to import plots from matplotlib into my LaTeX document, borrowing text formatting from the main document (so I want to avoid pure PDF). I am currently exporting the figure as  PGF.

When I save the figure as a PGF the settings (linewidths, markersizes, annotation text sizes, etc.) do carry over properly, but the font is not inherited from the document.

MWE:

Create the figure in python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams.update({'text.usetex': True})

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xlabel('my xlabel')
plt.ylabel('my ylabel')

plt.savefig('D:/_Current Work/fig.pgf')
```

LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\input{"D:/_Current Work/fig.pgf"}

\end{document}
```

The figure created will not change the font used in the tick labels and axes labels regardless of whether I include or omit the `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}` to change the font to sans-serif.

I've read many other posts on the forum about these two tools but it seems like this should work without any problems so I assume I am missing something basic.

## EDIT

A few users suggested this question is a duplicate of [Typeset mathematical symbols also in sans serif font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24035/188841). My problem seems to be the exact opposite of the question in the link: my math is being renderred according to the global math font correctly, but the normal text is not.

Comment: I believe I have found the problem. It is to do with matplotlib's exporting to a PGF, which forces a font family upon all text, even if none is specified (in which case it uses the default sans-serif family).

The question now becomes how do I stop matplotlib from adding a font family to text entries. This is a question for StackOverflow, not TeX.StackExchange. I have posted a new question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56280224/7530580)

Comment: As a temporary fix, you can replace every occurrence of `sffamily` with `rmfamily` in the figure using `sed -i 's/sffamily/rmfamily/g' fig.pgf` (or `sed -i '' 's/sffamily/rmfamily/g' fig.pgf` on macos)

Comment: A similar comment was made in StackOverflow. The problem is that I do not want to specify a font at all, but I imagine your macro can be rewritten to just delete `\sffamily` rather than replace it with `\rmfamily`.

Alternatively, a user [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286426/7530580) to use `\renewcommand\sffamily{}` inside the figure enviornment, which has a similar effect.

Comment: Maybe just replace `sffamily` with `normalfont`.