# Why doesn't newtxsf typeset all mathematical symbols in sans serif?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, sans-serif

I am looking for a nice sans serif math font to go with *Fira Sans* for beamer slides. I read the different suggestions in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24035/typeset-mathematical-symbols-also-in-sans-serif-font) and found `newtxsf` to be the most fitting package. Indeed, it does look beautiful on lowercase greek letters, but for some reason, uppercase greek letters and numbers are still typeset in a serif font.

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the sans serif math package `newtxsf` change the shape of the uppercase greek letters and numbers?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathrm{Fira Sans}
\setmathsf{Fira Sans}
\setmathtt{Fira Sans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\begin{document}
\frame{
Numbers outside of math mode: 12345.

Number in math mode: $12345$.

Capital letters in math mode: $AB\Gamma\Delta$.

Small letters in math mode: $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Minuscules in sans serif, capital letters in serif font.]

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why `\setmathtt{Fira Sans}`? Wouldn't `\setmathtt{Fira Mono}` be more appropriate?

Comment: Oh. This probably was an artifact from some other bugfix attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must admit to not understanding the logic behind the instructions in the preamble of your document. The following, simpler setup would appear to work just fine:

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono} % optional
\usepackage{newtxsf}
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

Aside: If you wanted *slanted* rather than upright uppercase Greek letters, load `newtxsf` with the option `slantedGreek`. (`uprightGreek` is the default.) If, on the other hand, you want lowercase *and* uppercase Greek letters to be rendered using upright glyphs, load the `newtxsf` package with the option `frenchmath`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% \usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'beamer'
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Numbers, text mode: 12345

Numbers, math mode: $12345$

Uppercase greek letters, math mode: $\Gamma\Delta\Psi\Omega$

Lowercase greek letters, math mode: $\gamma\delta\psi\omega$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the *Fira Math* font. It obviously pairs well with *Fira Sans*. Here is an example (it works for me with `lualatex` but doesn't work with `xelatex` for some reason)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\begin{document}
\frame{
Numbers outside of math mode: 12345.

Number in math mode: $12345$.

Capital letters in math mode: $AB\Gamma\Delta$.

Small letters in math mode: $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$.

Formula:
\[
  \int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+(i/n)^2}.
\]
}
\end{document}
```

[image]:

Comment: Thank you. This also answers my question, but unfortunately it doesn't render `\mathfrak` as fraktur letters (which I also need throughout my document).

Comment: Yes, Fira Math doesn't have all the math glyphs yet. If I need some that is missing, I use some other font just for it. Just add `\setmathfont[range=frak]{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range=]{Fira Math}` after the `\setmathfont`.

Comment: @Lukas GFS Neohellenic Math might be a good companion, since it has very faint slab serifs. `\setmathfont[range={frak,bffrak}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{GFS Neohellenic Math}`.