# STIX fonts & TL2013 packaging

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

Based on the discussion here

[Is it already possible to use the STIX fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/720/is-it-already-possible-to-use-the-stix-fonts)

it appears that the STIX project (release 1.1) supports LaTeX; I'm eager to get started with them!

TL2013 does have a current `stix` package, which is based on release 1.0 and does not provide LaTeX support.

**Question.** Is there a reason that TL hasn't upgraded to version 1.1, or is this just a matter of time (and patience)? If there is a significant obstacle, could someone explain?

(I am aware that one could--in principle--install STIX v1.1 (or, of course, 1.2) by hand, but I am not exactly sure how to do that.)

Comment: Since this is quite TL specific, why don't you ask in the TL mailing list?

Comment: I installed the fonts in the “local” tree, that is, under `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`, added `Map stix.map` to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg` and run `updmap-sys`.

Comment: Besides, TL depends on authors uploading to CTAN...

Comment: Work was still underway on the latex support for the stix fonts when tex live 2013 was frozen.  it should be ready for inclusion in tl2014.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, don't they just upload it when it is done such that it gets pushed out as a normal update?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I see; so STIX LaTeX support won't officially make it in until TL2014. That's what I was afraid of!

Comment: @egreg Thanks very much for the installation directions. I'll try it!

Comment: i'm not sure when it will be finished; testing of the beta is well along. @daleif -- yes, it should be uploaded to ctan as soon as it is ready, and the tex live crew takes in updates as they appear on ctan.

Comment: @daleif Maybe this post is inappropriate for tex.sx? If so, is there way I can delete it so that it doesn't clutter things up?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think you should convert your last comment to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as of now (november 2013), testing of the beta of the latex support for the stix fonts
is well along.  some work is needed on the fonts themselves, and i'm not sure when it
will be ready for final release.  however, i'm optimistic that it can happen before
tex live 2014 is frozen.

the fonts and supporting package will certainly be uploaded to ctan as soon as they
are ready, and the tex live crew takes in updates as they appear on ctan.

Answer (score 3):

As of today (Jan 5), TL has LaTeX support for the STIX fonts (and version 1.1 of the OpenType fonts).