# What font or symbol is this in Latex?

Tags: fonts, symbols

Can anybody recognize the font or symbol for this [image]. It is used as font for alphabetic letter S, in my text.

I did check almost all fonts and symbols but couldn't succeed in finding a good match. I need this symbol in Latex math mode.

Or a way, to design this symbol by myself to be use in Latex.
thanks

Comment: Helpful/related: [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098)

Answer (score 1):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
% search http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124 for a mathcal font you like (boondox and boondoxo look similar) and do:
$\mathcal{S}$
% or use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with unicode-math and do:
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}$\mscrS$\setmathfont{Cambria Math}$\mscrS$\setmathfont{XITS Math}$\mscrS$
% or search some font on your system http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%F0%9D%92%AE+-+MATHEMATICAL+SCRIPT+CAPITAL+S+%28U%2B1D4AE%29 and use fontspec (Xe- or LuaLaTeX):
\setmainfont{stix-italic.otf}\symbol{"1D4AE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using pdflatex, is it possible to use the last font of S shown above i-e $\mscrS$.

Comment: @kaka Please see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96911