# Using stix fonts with pdfLaTeX: "Option clash for package textcomp."

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex, stix

This is a follow-up question for [Is it already possible to use the STIX fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/720/is-it-already-possible-to-use-the-stix-fonts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I would like to use stix font in my thesis. I am using pdflatex with MiKTeX (probably the latest version). My question is that whether I can simply call `\usepackage{stix}` for using the font or should I have to install the font separately i.e. the latest MiKTeX does not include this font.

Suppose, if the latest Miktex package doesn't include this, could anyone of you guide me how to do the same.

Thanks!!

**Update 1**:

As egreg and  Joseph Wright mentioned I used the stix package in my document which returned this following error as follows:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

Comment: Did you try `\usepackage{stix}` before asking the question?

Comment: https://miktex.org/packages/stix

Comment: @egreg it threw me an error, saying there is an option clash with the package  ''text comp''

Comment: @RaajaG Please edit the text of the error into the question

Comment: Apparently you're loading `textcomp` before `stix` (directly or via another package). Please add a minimal example of a document showing the behavior. However, if you have `\usepackage{textcomp}` in your document, just remove it.

Comment: @egreg I tried that as well. Now I shall try to post a MWE for this issue. I don't know what other package makes an implicit call to textcomp. I shall check that!!

Comment: Thanks egreg and John Wright for your suggestive comments!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `stix` package [is included in MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/packages/stix). It can be loaded with a very short example such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}

Hello world
\[
  y = mx + c
\]

\end{document}
```

---

The error in the question indicates that `textcomp` is being loaded twice with different options. The `stix` package loads it with the `full` option. You may therefore either drop `textcomp` from your 'real' document or tell `stix` not to load it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notextcomp]{stix}
\begin{document}

Hello world
\[
  y = mx + c
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!

Comment: +1 for the `notextcomp` option -- works also with `kpfonts`.