# Problem With stix Package

Tags: errors, packages, stix

I start using stix package for mathematics arrows , and I get this error along with others which are very similar

```
    -Too many symbol fonts declared. ...ont{arrows2} {LS1}{stixsf} {m}{it}
  - Symbol font `arrows2' not defined. ...arrows2} {bold}{LS1}{stixsf} {b}{it}
   -Unknown symbol font `arrows2'. ...areSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsfit}{arrows2}
......
```

here s my MWE(with all the packages i used):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{setspace} % increase interline spacing slightly
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{bsymb,b2latex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  
\usepackage{verbatim}  
\usepackage{vector}  
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\def\gtA{\ensuremath{\rhd\mkern-14mu-}}
\def\ltA{\ensuremath{\lhd\mkern-14mu-}}
\usepackage[savewrites,nopostdot,toc,acronym,nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\usepackage{oz,amsfonts}  %for Z notation
\usepackage{bsymb,b2latex}
\usepackage[notextcomp]{stix}

\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

$   \begin{array}{l}
    f \in S \nvrightarrowtail T\\
    f \in S \rightarrowtail T \\
    f \in S \nvtwoheadrightarrow T\\
    f \in S \twoheadrightarrow T\\
    f \in S \twoheadrightarrowtail T
    \end{array}$
\end{document}
```

here where you can find the B2latex and bsymb styles : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By0MmMuqlhl1TEZhYTdVNE5FdGM

thank you for your help

Comment: You can probably very easily figure that out yourself. Comment out package by package, and see when the error disappears. Edit: I see though that you have `\hypersetup` without loading `hyperref`, so probably whichever class you're using loads some packages as well.

Comment: I found that the problem is whith the two packages \usepackage{stix} and \usepackage{oz,amsfonts }%for Z notation, i can't delete one one them , what should I do ? Ps: I did load hyperref package in another file , my document worked perfectly before adding stix

Comment: @Nousa: Sometimes changing the order of loading the packages can help. Try to load the `stix` package before `oz` etc.

Comment: Did it really work perfectly? `oz` also conflicts with `amsmath`, though the error is different. But those three alone do not generate any errors relating to `textcomp`, so your documentclass must be loading `textcomp`. But try `\usepackage[notextcomp]{stix}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342797/using-stix-fonts-with-pdflatex-option-clash-for-package-textcomp

Comment: `\usepackage[notextcomp]{stix}` works for textcomp error ,  i changed the order of package but still i get error such : `Too many symbol fonts declared. ...ont{arrows2} {LS1}{stixsf} {m}{it}`, Symbol font `arrows3' not defined. ...arrows3} {bold}{LS2}{stixtt} {b} {n} .....

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating this? Add a link to where the `bsymb` and `b2latex` packages can be found, they're not standard packages.

Comment: I downloaded bsymb and b2latex in my working directory , I posted my MWE in the original question, I dont know how to fix such error ,I'm stuck

Comment: A couple of things about your last update: 1) the error you mention it presumably not the same that your example generates, so perhaps you could change that, to avoid confusion. 2) Do you really need all of that code to demonstrate the problem? The smaller the example, the easier it is for others to figure out. 3) Can you add a link to where we can download `bsymb` and `b2latex`? 4) `hyperref` should typically be loaded much later, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I can't fully compile your code since my system (macTeX2016) doesn't seem to feature the packages `bsymb`, `b2latex`, and `vector`.

Ignoring this issue, i.e., commenting out the instructions that load these three packages, I get the error message:

```
LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.
```

What to do? Well, which packages among the ones that are currently loaded provide symbol fonts? The two main candidates are `fourier` and `stix`. As it can serve no good purpose to load both `fourier` and `stix`, I suggest you load only one package or the other, *but not both*. That way, happily, the aforementioned LaTeX error disappears on its own.

Aside: You should really take some time to organize and simplify your document preamble. Don't load packages twice, don't run `\hypersetup` twice, determine whether you really need most of those packages to begin with, and get rid of statements such as `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` which can't serve any useful purpose if either the `fourier` package or the `stix` package is what you really. Do you need the `latexsym` and `amsfonts` packages, given that `stix` provides lots of symbols? Do you really need the `oz` and `multicol` packages?  The list goes on...

Comment: Yes, the `textcomp` issue was resolved (see comments), the `too many symbol fonts` is what the example should show I believe.

Comment: Works as magic , thanks a lot ( i just delete the `fourier ` package ) @TorbjørnT, @Mico I appreciate your help ,Thank you so much

Comment: Besides, `fourier` also changes the default math codes at begin document, so even if `stix` didn't balk for “too many symbol fonts”, the math would be quite wrong nonetheless.