# How do I convert a character to a numeric value?

Tags: macros, symbols, unicode

Now that I've gotten Will Robertson's excellent [unicode-math](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/unicode-math.html) package working to change the colour and style of letters in my mathematics (trust me, there *is* a reason) thanks to his answer to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335/can-i-change-the-font-and-colour-of-a-letter-permanently), I want to figure out how to implement this properly.

The key step seems to be that the command to change how a letter is displayed needs the unicode numerical value of the letter.  The example that Will gave was:

```
\setmathfont[range="66,math-style=upright,Colour=FF0000]{xits-math.otf}
```

(font name changed to work with xelatex as per Will's comment on that question) which changes the letter `e`.  But I want a command that I can invoke as `\type{constR}{e}` (which should declare `e` to be a constant real number).  So I need to convert `e` to its unicode value.

Now it seems possible that there isn't a general "charater to unicode" command, so I'd be content if I could convert a standard letter to some number since the characters that I'm most going to use this on are the alphanumerics.  Thus:

> What's the best way to convert an alphanumerical character to a position in the alphabet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a general way of converting a character to its char number (which is equivalent to its unicode glyph slot in unicode), but it unfortunately doesn't work well in options to fontspec/unicode-math (an issue I'm aware of). Usually you can use something like this:

```
\newcount\foo
\foo=`\e
```

to assign the char number of "e" to \foo; this "backtick-escape" syntax works wherever TeX expects a number. However, it *doesn't* work if the argument is being expanded first, which is what happens in fontspec & unicode-math.

Now, you don't *actually* need the backslash in the code above; this will work too:

```
\foo=`e
```

The difference is that this cannot be used for "difficult" characters such as `%` and `#`. If you're just using letters, this won't be a problem.

So in unicode-math you should be able to write

```
range={`e,`j,...}
```

Or with whatever letters you need.

Comment: Works fine for me with `unicode-math`!  Both directly and via a wrapper macro.

Comment: For these "difficult" characters, when they have to go through a round of expansion, an incantation like `\expandafter\@gobble\string\%` could help. Of course put in a macro.

Answer (score 0):

(I would have added this as a comment, but I don't yet have enough reputation points to comment.)

Adding on to Will Robertson's answer for the case where you have a macro (defined in LaTeX in the form `\newcommand\mychar{}`) which expands to a character, one can get the code for the expanded macro by doing `` \makeatletter\foo=\expandafter`\mychara \relax\makeatother ``.