# Changing the kpfonts \sum symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

I like the kpfonts package. It's a nice font and some of the extra symbols it defines are sometimes useful. But I do not like the `\sum` symbol either in displaystyle or inline. It's too thin and too tall. I tried looking at how kpfonts defines `\sum` in the hope of just being able to `\renewcommand` but it does something weird with the maths operators, in order to have package options like `fullsumlimits`.

How can I get the `\sum` symbol looking more like the cm sum, for example, without breaking kpfonts package options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/how-do-i-change-the-font-of-a-letter).

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\sumop\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{"50}
```

That gets you the `\sum` from Computer Modern but called `\sumop`. With `kpfonts` loaded, that should make the macro `\sum` respect the various limits option while using the CM sum symbol.

Comment: This fix works, but it breaks the fullsumlimits option in kpfonts. kpfonts has a weird way of defining the operators that involves an extra command.

Comment: @Seamus: I believe that edit should address your comment.

Comment: The middle line should be `\let\sumop\relax` otherwise all the sums just disappear!

Comment: Good catch. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @TH. how can i replace all math symbols with the exception for the normal letters  a,b,c... and the \hbar command from computer modern or the mathdesign package ? and how i can know if this substitution is typographically correct?