# Is there a readymade symbol for a 90 degrees rotated \Bowtie?

Tags: symbols

**Where do I find a symbol that looks like a slightly smaller version of a 90 degrees rotated `\Bowtie` from the `wasysym` package?**

Something like [image].

I couldn't find anything in the usual tables. The [detexify site](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) yields nothing close. I managed the following hack (which defines a binary operator):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{wasysym,graphicx}  
\newcommand{\uproduct}{\mathbin{\;{\rotatebox{90}{$\small\Bowtie$}}}}
\begin{document}  
$A \uproduct B$  
\end{document}
```

It produces [image]. Although it looks OK here, it looks bad when used in a subscript. This is surely not the right solution. I'd well believe that a solution using metafont exists, but would prefer something less esoteric. Perhaps there is a standard symbols package that I overlooked?

---

**EDIT: Geoffrey and Aditya gave admirable solutions for creating this symbol (I'm sorry for previously calling them "hacks"). And Seamus found a font package.

Comment: Konrad I suggested the \scalebox, but I am very curious as to where you are using it. I presume as a relational symbol for a join? Never thought of it as a subscript!

Comment: I'd like to use it for the join of two graphs. It would be a nice suggestive notation. And in principle something like $G_1\uproduct G_2$ could end up in a sub- or superscript somewhere.

Comment: Konrad, don't worry. The given solutions (well, at least mine ;) ) are not "hacks". Of course it would be nice if every conceivable symbol were natively available. However, it's quite usual to construct one when this can't be. The `\mathchoice`-based solution should be safe to most contingencies. `\mathchoice` (like `\;`, `\[` etc) is a TeX primitive, aditya's `\mathpalette` comes from `plain.tex`, `\scalebox` from `graphics.sty` and `\rotatebox` from `graphicx.sty` have both been around for 15+ years. I.e., 99.99% of the problems that might surface have already been ironed out. Rest easy. :)

Comment: And you will be surprised how many of the basic math symbols are made using similar techniques :)

Comment: @Geoffrey and Aditya: thanks for the reassurances and for providing some perspective.

Comment: The two solutions that modify existing symbols have the advantage that they don't need the `mathdesign` package, which seems as if can only be used with one of three typefaces (one, garamond, is not included in TeXLive). On the other hand, `\udtimes` seems to space nicely in these three fonts, something that doesn't happen with the other two solutions. Changing the spacing with `\,`, `\;`, etc., behaves differently when the font is changed.

Comment: The Unicode symbol is `U+29D6 WHITE HOURGLASS`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\udtimes` is defined in the [`mathdesign`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/) package

Comment: But I expect it's just a macro defined more or less as the above "hacks" define it...

Comment: Ah, this is it! But do you know how to use mathdesign If I don't want utopia, chrter or garamond?

Comment: You might be able to modify this question to answer that question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2997/changing-the-kpfonts-sum-symbol

Comment: The symbol appears on page 8 of this document: http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/mathdesign/MD-adobe-utopia-doc.pdf (I don't know enough to write the code, but that should give you enough information to work it our)

Answer (score 4):

I think that judiciously combining `\mathchoice`, `\rotatebox` and `scalebox` should give you what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wasysym}

\newcommand\uproduct{%
  \mathchoice{\mathbin{\;\rotatebox{90}{$\Bowtie$}}}%
             {\mathbin{\;\rotatebox{90}{$\Bowtie$}}}%
             {\mathbin{\;\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{0.65}{$\Bowtie$}}}}%
             {\mathbin{\;\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{0.65}{$\Bowtie$}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
  $A = B \uproduct C$, whereas $X_{B \uproduct C} > Y$
  \[
    A=\sum_{B \uproduct C}^{D \uproduct E}{F \uproduct G}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Of course, the spacing and the scaling are still up to you.

Comment: Aha, this is what my hack should have been! And you're right: the spacing and scaling still have to be tweaked somewhat.

Comment: Part of the problem is that `\\Bowtie` itself doesn't scale when used in a subscript, which means that `wasysym` is not perfect. On the other hand, `\\udtimes` from Seamus's answer does scale.

Comment: @Konrad, of course.  That's why `\mathchoice` was implemented early on in TeX. Native font characters like `mathdesign`'s `\udtimes` are always the best way to go if you can. I'd definitely go for it if you're OK with using (or at least loading) `mathdesign` within your work. In any event, now you're aware of the TeX-general approach to cleanly solving your problem. Useful to know for those times when loading in another font package isn't the ideal way to go (e.g., if it changes your typography in ways you don't want or interferes with other code you use).

Answer (score 4):

In modern TeX engines (`XeTeX`, `LuaTeX`), this symbol is avaiable with [`unicode-math`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) as `\hourglass`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
    \(A\hourglass B\)
\end{document}
```

[image: output result]

Comment: Great! I've tried it using xelatex, which didn't work, and using lualatex, which did work. Any reason for the difference? (I used MacTex, Tex Live 2011.)

Comment: @KonradSwanepoel For me, it works with both engines, so it shouldn't be a general problem with `XeTeX`. Did you run `fc-cache` before using `xelatex` (see [Lualatex sees a font while fc-list doesn't](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20171/3323))?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt with slightly better spacing:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\douproduct[1]%
  {\mathbin
  {\m@th\leavevmode\raisebox{-0.03ex}
    {\vbox{\baselineskip\z@skip \lineskip-.2ex% =0.25*0.8
     \ialign{##\cr
     \rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{0.8}{$#1\triangleleft $}}\cr
     \rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{0.8}{$#1\triangleright$}}\cr}}}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\uproduct{\mathpalette\douproduct\relax}
```

Comment: It's a little too high when used in a subscript, although the symbol _is_ smaller.

Comment: Try the updated version.

Comment: The updated one doesn't compile properly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a `\makeatletter` in the beginning. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the `\scalebox` command for example:

```
\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{0.5}{$\Bowtie$}}
```

The `\scalebox` can virtually scale anything.

Comment: This gives the same behaviour: it doesn't scale right in  a subscript.

Comment: You can change the scaling factor and you can also raise it or lower it if you like. However, I agree with you a readymade symbol will always look better. Thanks for the comment on usage.