# LuaLaTeX sees a font while fc-list doesn't

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I've got a fresh Arch Linux box with fresh full TeX Live installed. The installation seems to include `cm-unicode` fonts and `lualatex` seems to find them correctly, but when I run `fc-list` the output contains only a couple of system fonts. How can I get the list of available fonts? Is there any way to fix `fc-list` or should I use another utility?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, LuaLaTeX doesn't use `fc-list`, but rather caches fonts using luaotfload.lua.

In order to make all otf fonts in TeX Live known to your system, run

```
cp $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
fc-cache -fsv
```

as superuser. This is actually necessary for XeTeX and XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

you can create a local config file `.fonts.conf` in your home directory if you have no root access:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
 <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
 <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
 <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintmedium</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```