# Quarterly filled circle symbol

Tags: symbols

For a comparison table I am using the symbols of `wasysym` which gives me an empty circle, a full circle and also half filled circle.

However I would rather use a more fine grained sale and for this I need also a quarterly filled circle and a circle which is filled by 3/4.

Does anyone know if such symbols exist in any LaTeX package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @percusse and voters for closing: did *you* check that the required symbols are there? They aren't.

Comment: @egreg It's in the `universal` package under `\bauquarter` macro

Comment: Or `\manfilledquartercircle` from `manfnt` to be combined with an empty circle.

Comment: for whatever it's worth, these symbols are in unicode as U+25D4 and U+25D5, so should be in the xits and stix fonts.

Comment: @percusse There's only *one* of the possible 3/4 filled circles (of course one can rotate it), but there's no 1/4 filled one. And you might have added the package and the macro to the comment.

Comment: I apologize for my laziness. egreg is right. The required info was missing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not the best macro in the world, but perhaps something like

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\pie}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (1ex);\fill (1ex,0) arc (0:#1:1ex) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

And an example

```
Hello world \pie{90} \pie{120} \pie{240} \pie{270}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: +1 nicely done! It's generally best to post a *complete* MWE though; just remember it for next time :)

Comment: Thanks, however I would need the circle to work "clockwise". Your solution is elegant, however it has its origin not at the top of the circle and it goes counter-clockwise... I tried to modify your macro, however it always did mess up the arc... can you help me out?

Comment: @Conman Just put `-#1` inside the macro or enter the angles with a minus sign e.g. `\pie{-120}`

Comment: @percusse: Yes, you are right, that changes the dircetion into clock-wise, however the "origin" is still not at the top but instead at 3 o'clock... any idea how to fix this, too?

Comment: Got it myself: \fill[rotate=90] does that. Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 3):

Circle with upper right quadrant black: ◔
Unicode hexadecimal: 0x25d4
In block: Geometric Shapes

There are probably symbols that black each of the four quadrants separately, or you can rotate this one: see [Is there a readymade symbol for a 90 degrees rotated \Bowtie?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3495/is-there-a-readymade-symbol-for-a-90-degrees-rotated-bowtie) for rotation code.

I found the answer with http://shapecatcher.com/.

**Edit:**
@Barbara Beeton comments above ... these symbols are in unicode as U+25D4 and U+25D5, so should be in the xits and stix fonts. Then the answer here may help: [Is it already possible to use the STIX fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/720/is-it-already-possible-to-use-the-stix-fonts)

Comment: Thanks! can you tell me how to insert this unicode symbol in my latex document?

Comment: @Conman Answer edited with information I hope helps.