# What's the proper way to typeset a differential operator?

Tags: typography, math-operators

I can't seem to find any consensus on the right way to typeset a differential operator, whether it is:

- in a standalone context: [image: standalone differential]
- as part of a derivative: [image: derivative]
- as part of an integral: [image: integral]

In all of these cases, I have seen them sometimes italicized like variables (as in the second and third examples above) and sometimes not italicized like operator names (as in the first example above). There is also additional variation in how much spacing goes between the "d" and whatever it is acting on.

Seeing as this is an incredibly common symbol in many branches of mathematics, I am curious about the lack of standardization -- I've seen all possible combinations used in all possible contexts by many respected authors and publishers.

Are there any rules of thumb that I can follow? I personally tend to prefer the non-italicized version with very little space next to it, so I add:

```
\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{d}\!{#1}}}
```

to my default preamble, and use that everywhere, but I'd like to know if I'm breaking any hard-and-fast rules here.

Comment: Some related issues: should Euler's e be italicized? how about the imaginary unit i? should single-letter subscripts that are not variables/indices be italicized (eg, "f" in t-subscript-f representing a "final" time)? (Everyone seems to agree that multi-letter subscripts of this type should be roman). My opinion (seems to be shared by many British publishers) is that these should all be roman, along with the differential d. Many US publishers make them all italic. Perhaps there are publishers who use a mix of both, but I don't remember seeing it.

Comment: Constants like e and i should also be upright. This is covered in the document.

Comment: Interesting -- I was surprised to read that particular rule in the "standard". Still, that seems to be a rule that is *universally* ignored, whereas the differential rule seems to be split approximately down the middle.

Comment: By the by, I asked this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2969/86 partly so that I could write `\int_0^1 e^{2\pi i t} d t` and have the `e`, `\pi`, `i`, `d` all automatically typeset upright.

Comment: Of course, Leibniz didn't think of `d` as an operator.  He thought `dx` was an infinitesimal—something smaller than any positive number but greater than 0.

Comment: Springer-Verlag's monograph style had `\def\D{\mathrm{d}}` for the differential operator. I agree with Hendrik Vogt's post below for spacing, that one should *typically* (but not always) write `\,\D x`. The exception: after a fraction, e.g., `\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\D x` is OK; and after a function, e.g., `\cos(x)\D x` is also OK. But I think there is no single golden rule...it's an art, not a science.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178946/better-automatic-spacing-of-differential-d

Comment: Related from the historical perspective: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6727/3462

Comment: @Emre, your [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator#comment27456_14821) says "This is covered in the document."  What document?  (EDIT:  Oh, is it the document linked in your [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14822)?)

Comment: Came here looking for `∂` (the nabla operator) which can be obtained with `\partial` - hope this could help somebody like me :)

Comment: @Cadoiz -- nabla is an upside-down Delta.  partial is the shape you show.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

There is a standard: it should be upright, not italicized. Read [Typesetting mathematics for science and technology according to ISO 31/XI](https://tug.org/tugboat/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf)

<s>I suggest using the [commath](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/commath) package to correctly typeset differentials.</s>

**Edit by @Gaussler in 2022:** The package `commath` is just an old collection of poorly written macros. The presence of better, modern alternatives (see the other answers, especially [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88961/19809) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637613/19809)) renders it completely obsolete. There is therefore no reason to use `commath` in 2022.

Comment: I'm glad to know that my instinct was right, and thanks for the link :) However, if this is a fixed, agreed-upon standard, do you have any insight into why it is so regularly violated? Even by authors like Michael Spivak, who definitely should know better.

Comment: (1) Because most mathematicians (who are, after all, the main group of people writing the most mathematics) are not typography experts, and could care less about your ISO standard. In general, just because something is "standard" doesn't mean people will use/follow it. (2) Because most people are lazy and `dx` is easier to type than `\D{x}`

Comment: Also, you may want to read the three paragraphs under item 6 on page 41 (3 out of 10 in the pdf) of the article Emre linked to. It sort of also answers your follow-up question.

Comment: @Willie: I'm not entirely satisfied by that argument; because mathematicians in general do go to great lengths to have consistent and attractive notation. I regularly see mathematical papers in LaTeX doing much more onerous things than spending three extra keystrokes to get a proper differential. Spivak wrote an entire book about properly typesetting formulas, and he still uses the "incorrect" *dx*. I suspect it has more to do with a genuine difference in opinion than pure laziness. But I suppose this is not the sort of question that it is easy to settle definitively in either direction :)

Comment: @WillieWong: Ah, thanks for that precise reference. It does explain things somewhat that house styles had become entrenched before a "standard" was agreed upon which took into consideration other fields like physics.

Comment: "Consistent and attractive" `=/=` ISO standard, that was sort of my point in (1). You say `dx` is "incorrect", but by whose authority? Who actually agreed upon the standards? To paraphrase Pete Clark, mathematicians are harder to herd than cats.  Also, my previous point (2) was meant to be a bit facetious, you know.

Comment: @Adrian I think that one argument that Willie left out was that if you've never seen something typeset a different way, you may never realise that there is a different way to do it.  Seeing _dx_ all my life, I never thought that an upright 'd' may be better until I happened to be trying to decide what colour 'd' should be!  Then I realised that 'd' was an operator, so should be typeset as such, and that operators were typeset as upright (and blue, since you ask).

Comment: I have to say seeing so many switches between upright and italic makes me dizzy.  It's nice to know that there's a standard, but it only makes me a teensy bit guilty to follow my aesthetic sense.  I just sampled 20 textbooks on my shelf and not a single one used an upright *d*.

Comment: @Andrew: the 'd' is *not* an operator. That's where the ISO people is wrong.

Comment: @egreg: Hmmm, I'd say that `\int ... d.` is an operator.  So the `d` by itself may not be an operator but together with the `\int` it becomes one.

Comment: @Andrew: not at all, dx is simply the name of a function (an element in the dual basis ...); but it's clearly OT. `;-)` The vast majority of mathematicians use an italic d, and Knuth himself does. `:-)`

Comment: There is a problem with `commath`: writing `\dif^2` or `\Dif^2` puts too small space before the superscript. And in some cases you can't use `\pd` instead.

Comment: As noted by @egreg most mathematicians use an italic _d._ Most physicists use an upright _d._ I had a look as some math and pysics books and math (physics) books always us an italic (upright) _d._ The advice to use the `commath` package is therefore most likely wrong if you're a mathematician because the package typesets the _d_ using `\mathrm`. The reference  [_Claudio Beccari's paper_](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf) is good, but I wouldn't recommend the `commath` package. Perhaps the _cool_ package is better because it lets you configure the style.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I wouldn't recommend `commath` in any case: it's just a collection of poorly written macros (see the definition of `\pd` to see what I mean).

Comment: @egreg I agree but I didn't have room to put that into my comment:-) Also I noticed that markup commands get counted as characters:-( I improved my comment a bit. The `cool` package provides some support for configuring the style of the variable of integration (_d_).

Comment: @Marc I just found that `commath` uses `\DeclareMathOperator` for `\dif`.
@egreg The `\pd` definition is very close to what I would define, given that I don't know much about the correct way to do it. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: @marczellm Thanks. I wasn't aware of this. I browsed the documentation but didn't notice it. I was worried the packages wasn't configurable.

Comment: "**For science and technology**" are key words, IMHO :).

Comment: @Alexey The scope of the standard is described as: "The recommendations in ISO 80000-2 are intended mainly for use in the natural sciences and technology, but also apply to other areas where mathematics is used."

Comment: @Loong, it would be funny though if they tried to recommend such standards for the mathematics itself.

Comment: @egreg dx is the name of a function? I thought dx is the differential of the variable x, meaning an infinitesimally small variation of the x. But maybe it's the same thing? Could you explain better (after 11 years! I don't think this minute thing is worth a new question, though. And certainly not in Tex)?

Comment: @Andyc Infinitesimal variation? Well, things have changed in the last 200 years. Unless you're doing physics, where the idea still runs on (but is wrong nonetheless).

Comment: @egreg I still don't get it. How is dx in mathematics a function like, say, f(x)? What would be its meaning? If it's too long to explain in a comment, you can point me to some (hopefully concise) literature.

Comment: @Andyc The function is f, not f(x)

Comment: @egreg Oh, ok, I see. My bad. I guess I'm not good enough at these things. I shall have to look up what "an element in the dual basis..." means.

Comment: irrespective of the setting of `d`  the `commath` package is not usable: it has far too many issues and is designed based on a misunderstanding of tex math mode tests https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135985/1090

Comment: @egreg The d in dx could be viewed as an operator (a linear operator from functions to differential forms), and x is a (local) coordinate (thus a function), and it seems more so when we talk about df.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Do you write all linear operators upright? The ISO norm, for example, doesn’t allow it.

Comment: @egreg I was just saying that, semantically, it makes sense to view this d as an operator. Mathematicians using italic d is historic and conventional (at least dating back to 1810s in Cauchy's papers), but not necessarily more reasonable.

Answer (score 97):

tl,dr:
It's complicated, but be consistent.

I believe the answers here tend to miss the point. While Emre mentions that there is an international norm regarding typesetting mathematics that is very explicit about this topic, Hendrik Vogt makes the right argument, but doesn't take it far enough. This question doesn't have an answer as simple as yes or no, rather it depends on your field, your publishers standard, the location you hail from and your wish for consistency. It's like asking what bibliography style is the right one for science. There are established traditions for typesetting mathematics, in part by the mathematical community of a country or family of countries, in part by the publishers. This transcends this question by far, since this touches a lot of other subjects, e.g. how ellipses, vectors and tensors look (this one has even more variety to offer than our subject) or the appearance of relation symbols, for example.

For example as [Beccari](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf) points out, this tradition of 'uprighting the differential' is less at home in the pure mathematics than it is in the applied variety or the neighbouring sciences. Physicists and engineers, for example, tend to lean towards the upright form more than the mathematicians.

This however is not even half of the picture, since there tend to be big differences when it comes to the nationality of an author. For example the style fans of slanted differentials are used to originates in the English speaking domain, and coincidental evidence, like all the books in your shelf adhering to that style, only tells us that the books you buy are likely by American publishers. Unfortunately not even the publishers are very consistent in what they put out. I once worked for a rather big European science publisher and on asking how they ensure consistency, they admitted they basically don't. They even just print a Word document, if that's what they get and \LaTeX ing it would be too much effort. Some things don't even have an established convention: I once tried to figure out the correct way to typeset the Laplacian symbol and literally every(!) book I picked up had a different style.

So for the issue at hand: in Russia the integral sign leans left instead of right ([Zaitsev](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301010726/https://www.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf)), while the upright school of thought (both integral and differential) originates in Central Europe, probably Germany. When you put the integrands at the end, like is common in parts of physics, the spacing also may change between the integral and the differential. Compare this sample to see what i mean:

[image: integrals in different traditions]

This shows why in my eyes it is not a very good idea to prescribe upright or slanted for the differential, since people then tend to overlook the integral sign and spacing issues involved, and there is a good chance that whatever answer you give them will be wrong.

Also it is not set in stone where to put the limits, even when adhering to a right leaning integral style, as Knuth has said himself (https://web.archive.org/web/20220303182058/http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf) (also see [Mathematics into Type](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf) by Swanson)

In German and Russian tradition, there are indeed conventions and norms where to put it that are adhered to, but even here discretion is advised. DIN, the German equivalent of ISO or ANSI, for example, has the norms 1302, 1304 and 1338 for typesetting mathematical formulas, similar to ISO 80000-2. These norms came out of the particular community and were mainly a write-up of the already established traditions. The ridiculous part comes in form of the DIN norms themselves, because they use the relation symbols inconsistently. The ones preferred by norm 1338 are [image: leqq] and [image: geqq], but the majority of the norms published after 1338 use [image: leg] and [image: geq]!, so all of this has to be taken with a grain of salt.

Now you can make an argument for uniformity in the way math is typeset, to make it easier to read and parse. In the end, it really doesn't matter too much, the most important question is, if people can understand it. If you write an undergrad text in your native language then it's likely better to adhere to the traditional style your crowd expects.

I recommend looking at where you come from, who you are writing for, making a choice about those questions and sticking to them! Consistency, within your own documents and even across them, is worth a lot more for your readers than trying to guess the conventions the biggest subset of them may be used to. Defining a macro for yourself that wraps all this and makes it easy to change the look with a simple change in one place is the best practical advice one can give.

It's interesting to note that in a way Latex itself has changed the picture, given its ubiquitous use in the mathematics and the fact that some choices are made for you via the default. A lot of people don't want to mess with things like the issue mentioned. Also, as [Zaitsev](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301010726/https://www.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf) mentioned, some things, like properly scaling the left leaning integral, seem to be quite hard to achieve, since Knuth didn't have those in mind when designing TeX.

Comment: i've seen the two-line less/greater-than or equal symbol used in the same document with a different meaning than the one-line version (although i can't put my hands on it just now), so even defining a norm can be counterproductive.  (after all, the first thing many mathematicians do is define their notation, which may be very idiosyncratic.)

Comment: One could add to your answer that the usage heavily depends on personal preferences. Even inside one community of mathematicians, it varies from author to author.

Comment: I really prefer ⩽ over ≤. Am I a communist now? ;) It just seems much more balanced than ≤. I guess it's better not to go against the tide here though :/

Comment: "Physicists and engineers, for example, tend to lean towards the upright form more than the mathematicians". This depends on where you're from. My experience, in an Australian university was the opposite. If you're to assert things like "the right argument", surely, scientists and mathematicians should be more concerned about what something actually means, not whether or not it's aesthetically pleasing or "most" people do it such and such a way. For example, the term "imaginary" originates in the concept of such numbers not being well received (mistakenly) by the establishment at the time.

Comment: Excellent answer. Especially with the image example

Comment: Of course: the Germans standardise literally everything. And if you want to have some fun, look for german laws: they have so many law books it's absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 90):

I'd say it really depends on the context. As Emre pointed out, there's an ISO standard; according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11), ISO 31-11 was superseded in 2009 by ISO 80000-2. The latter carries the title ["Quantities and units -- Part 2: Mathematical signs and symbols to be used in the natural sciences and technology"](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=31887).

As a mathematician I think: Why should I use the same notation as, say, an electrical engineer? In some of the sciences they may have good reasons for the choices in the ISO standard, but those reasons need not apply to every field that uses mathematical notation. It appears that I'm not in bad company here: Of course the TeXbook was written before ISO 31, but let me quote some examples from page 168:

[image]

On the same page, Knuth also uses the math italic `$e$` for the Euler number. For *mathematical* typesetting, I like Knuth's choices here very much. I can't say anything about other sciences.

Comment: knuth's choices were based on an extensive study of journals (including acta mathematica (swedish) and transactions of the american math society from the early 20th century) which were considered to have high typographical standards. it's also true that mathematicians came very late to the standards game, as opposed to engineers. (as a former u.s. representative on an iso working group on document processing, i have personal knowledge of this.) not all scientific and technical publishing has the same traditions.

Comment: @barbara: I thought Knuth would have done no less. I didn't write this in my answer, but this is somehow what I meant: It's OK to have different traditions and to follow these. Not everything has to be standardised.

Comment: Personally I prefer the differential operator upright. After all it is an abbreviation like tan or sin, why should this be any different? My late thesis supervisor drilled that in my head. He did type his thesis with an IBM golfball and used to brag about the care and time it took him to typeset it right. He was one of the first persons to adopt TeX in the RSA.

Comment: @Yiannis: It's a matter of personal taste. But I wouldn't regard "d" as an abbreviation for anything (e.g. "cos" is an abbreviation for "cosine", and the latter is what I _say_ when reading "cos").

Comment: Not sure why you're blaming us.  I just flipped through 6 of my electrical engineering textbooks and all of them use italic *d*.  Upright d looks strange to me, though my pedantic side is drawn to the logical distinction of it...

Comment: @endolith: I don't visit the site often and just found your comment. Sorry, I didn't mean to blame electrical engineers! I don't even remember how I came up with this example. Do you have a suggestion how I could improve my answer?

Comment: I'm not actually offended, just joking.  :D

Comment: @barbarabeeton Mathematicians might be late to the standards game, but they have been discussing how to typeset 'd' at least since Euler. See my answer [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7098/3462).

Comment: @Michael -- Thanks for the pointer to the history lesson.  May I have your permission to quote your words in a possible item in TUGboat?  (I assume the quotes from published sources are long out of copyright.  Please answer by email, to bnb at tug.org.)  I will also pass this information on to other interested parties.  Of note: confirmation that there's nothing on the topic in Cajori; I did try to look there several times for relevant information, but found none.

Comment: Presumably some mathematicians would want to use the same notation as an engineer because an engineer might end up using their maths, or even working with them?

Answer (score 46):

Upright feels more correct, but it is very rarely used and it looks ugly (though I may just think so because I'm so used to seeing the alternative). Personally, I prefer going with the alternative which is most often used and least ugly.

I use `\mathop{dx}` to get the correct spacing before and after differentials. Thus, it will be apparent that "dx" is its own entity, and not a d multiplied by an x, and it nicely separates the differentials:

[image: \int e^{-x^2-y^2}\mathop{dx}\mathop{dy}]

Comment: I completely agree with this, except "Upright feels more correct." Actually it _doesn't_, and all I know is how I saw my teachers and texts write _dx_ (with both italicized.. and this happens everywhere from _Numerical Recipes_ to _Salas and Hille's Calculus text_ to Schaum's outlines.) I've actually _never_, to my recollection, seen an upright d and an italicized x together, to my recollection.  Far as I'm concerned _dx_ is the correct way to right it.

Comment: `\mathop{dx}, {dv} {dt}` ... etc used for my thesis, simple and stand alone from other symbols.

Comment: +1 because this seems to be smart solution. But IMO something like \mathop{\mathrm{d}x} looks also decent.

Comment: Defining `\newcommand{\di}[1]{\mathop{d#1}}` is flexible so that you can write the economical `\di x \di y` etc.  I am an upright fan (since `d` is an operator) so for me it would be `\newcommand{\di}[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{d}#1}}`.

Answer (score 23):

I vote for upright e, i and d. In fact, I use upright and sans serif because it makes these symbols stand out clearly, but I haven't seen that used anywhere.

While we're at it, please allow me to point out that when "romanizing" multi-letter suffixes (like, say, "fin" for "final"), it's advisable to go for `\textnormal` rather than `\mathrm`, because the latter just renders a bunch of Roman characters side-by-side, without optimizing the spacing to make them look like the abbreviation to a single word.

Comment: Thank you for the `\textnormal` tip :) I honestly didn't expect to still be getting useful information out of this question 1.5 years after posting it!

Comment: There is also `\text` (from `amsmath` I think) but I don't know the typographic difference.

Comment: @marczellm `\textnormal{#1}` is basically `\text{\normalfont #1}` with some more tweaks. Therefore you use `\textnormal` for `sin`, but `\text` for `if and only if`. The reason is that `sin` should be upright even in for instance a theorem statement, whereas `if and only if` as a part of a displayed equation should be italic in a theorem statement (given you typeset theorems in italics).

Comment: @tohecz Thank you. I use `\sin` though :)

Comment: @marczellm That's of course correct. But if you wanted to define it manually, `\mathop{\textnormal{sin}}` would be much better than `\mathop{\text{sin}}`.

Comment: Or you could use ``\DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{sin}``, which I'm pretty sure is preferable to both. I believe you need the ``mathtools`` package for this, though.

Comment: @AbeSchulte `\DeclareMathOperator` is defined in `amsopn` which is loaded by `amsmath` (as stated in the [amsmath documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) section 6 *Call some other packages*).

Answer (score 21):

This covers the input side of things rather than the display side, but it’s a technique I’ve found useful:

In XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, I do something like this:

```
\newcommand*{\diffdchar}{d}    % or {ⅆ}, or {\mathrm{d}}, or whatever standard you’d like to adhere to
\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{\diffdchar\!}}
\catcode`\ⅆ=\active
\letⅆ=\dd
```

Edit: *Per* egreg’s comment, the [`newunicodechar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) package can make this easier, and will work for regular TeX (with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` applied):

```
\newcommand*{\diffdchar}{d}    % or {ⅆ}, or {\mathrm{d}}, or …
\newunicodechar{ⅆ}{\mathop{\diffchar\!}}
```

In either case,

```
$yⅆx-xⅆy$
$ⅆxⅆy=rⅆrⅆθ$    % Assuming Xe/LuaLatex, or \newunicodechar{θ}{\theta}

$xⅆy/ⅆx$         % For comparison;
$xⅆy/\!ⅆx$       % need spacing hack for linear fractions,
$x\frac{ⅆy}{ⅆx}$ % ... but built-up fractions are OK.
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what this ends up looking like? I don't have a copy of XeTeX/LuaTeX handy.

Comment: With the **newunicodechar** package this becomes `\newunicodechar{ⅆ}{\mathop{\diffchar\!}}`, but I'd prefer `\newunicodechar{ⅆ}{\mathop{}\!\diffchar}`.

Comment: @Adrian: the character that jcsalomon activates is U+2146 (DOUBLE-STRUCK ITALIC SMALL D), that's hardly ever used and stands up well in an editor window. The result is exactly the same as those presented in other answers. With **newunicodechar** XeTeX and LuaTeX are not needed, it also works with the standard `utf8` option for **inputenc**.

Comment: @egreg, is there any benefit to `\mathop{}\!\diffchar` over `\mathop{\diffchar\!}`?

Comment: @jcsalomon: It's just a personal preference of separating things clearly.

Comment: @egreg So for ordinary LaTeX (no XeTeX/LuaTeX), `\newcommand*{\diffd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` (no other braces needed, right?) is the best way of getting an *upright* (I know this is not your preference) differential symbol ("operator"), right?

Comment: @LoverofStructure, pretty much, yes; I separated out the choice of glyph for clarity, not utility.

Comment: This is a very nice answer because it not only addresses the problem but also gives a nice "interface" solution. It would be perfect if one could "type" these unicode characters directly. Does any body know how to associate key strokes with unicode characters? For example, to make, ctrl-alf-d to type ⅆ. I asked this with no satifactory answer some time ago: "Tool to create custom keyboard layouts for for unicode math?" http://askubuntu.com/questions/228050/is-there-a-tool-to-quickly-create-custom-keyboard-layouts-for-international-keyb. I use Fedora and `gedit`.

Comment: @alfC, in GNOME programs, hit Ctrl+Shift+U, then the Unicode character number in hexadecimal, _e.g._, Ctrl+Shift+U then 2146 then Space for “ⅆ”. (BTW, Texworks has a script that does something similar.)

Comment: @alfC, also see my https://gist.github.com/jcsalomon/1325295 where I’ve collected the Unicode characters I’ve found most useful into a handy reference sheet.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, I am exploring creating Snippets in Gedit to autmatically create unicode character with key combinations (or autotext) and at the same time using `\newunicodechar` in the document to customize the actual look in the document. I don't know how I didn't discover this before. I just typed this equation, which in normal latex would take several lines: `C⌄ℓ {ⅆT⌄ℓ⁄ⅆt}=∇(κ⌄ℓ  ∇T⌄ℓ) + G⌄{sℓ}(T⌄s - T⌄ℓ) + G⌄{eℓ}(T⌄e - T⌄ℓ)`, I was able to redifine the meaing of `⌄` as "text subscript". It is almost like typing rich-formatted equations with Mathematica. Very fast, consice and meaningful.

Comment: The negative thin space is usually good, but sometimes not. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178946/better-automatic-spacing-of-differential-d

Comment: @alfC: Can you elaborate on how you teach latex to translate these concise formulas into meaningful tex code? (I.e. do you have a file with tex command definitions you could share?)

Answer (score 20):

"Scientific Style and Format - The CSE Manual for Authors, Editors, and Publishers" suggests using roman(upright) d to typeset differential operators (CSE 7th ed, page 160). As someone already pointed out, authors, in general, don't care whether it shows up as italics dt or not. It is left mostly to technical copyeditors like me to fix this. - Dave Ledesma

Comment: I do care very much that it shows up as italic `:-)`

Answer (score 12):

Just to throw another option in the already muddy (or bloody?) water here. [The `physics` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/physics) contains its own set of automation for typesetting this stuff (including ordinary and partial derivatives) as well as automation for Dirac's quantum mechanics notation (bras and kets) and a number of odds and ends mostly related to re-sizing brackets and typesetting "evaluate at" indications.

Some basics from the package:

- For differentials: `\dd` or `\dd{x}`.
- For ordinary derivatives: `\dv{x}` for the derivative with respect to $x$ operator, `\dv{f}{x}` for the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and `\dv[2]{f}{x}` for the second derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.
- For partial derivatives: `\pdv{x}` for the partial derivative with respect to $x$ operator, `\pdv{f}{x}` for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and `\pdv[2]{f}{x}` for the second partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. `\pdv{f}{x}{y}` for the mixed partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.

  The [documentation](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf) does not indicate if this extends to higher mixed derivatives or not; experiment shows that `\pdv{f}{x}{y}{z}` does **not** generate the third partial derivative with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$ but typesets as `\pdv{f}{x}{y}` followed by $z$.

This package uses roman d's and italic type for the quantity whose differential it is in keeping with the standard that [Emre cites](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14822/327) (and therefore at odds with the history of mathematical typesetting as noted by many posters herein).

Comment: The package also has the `italicdiff` option for printing the differential d in italics. `:-)`

Comment: The package has `{}`-delimited optional arguments, which is a deadly sin

Comment: Note that we can italicize the d's using `\usepackage[italicdiff]{physics}`.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a newcomer to mathematics, so maybe there's an obvious reason why nobody else has suggested this … but personally, I find *slanted* (but still roman) `d`'s to look most attractive, and yet be “most differentiable” (pun intended ) from possible variables named ‘d’ or operators with an upright, roman ‘d’ in their name:

```
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\textnormal{\slshape d}}
\begin{document}

\[
d(x) = \frac{\dif}{\dif x}
   \left(
      x \cdot \mathop{\mathrm{dep}}(x)
   \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Here's a sample of the output. Beautiful, easy to tell at a glance what-is-what, and adheres to the *spirit* of the ISO standard, while maintaining the beauty and traditional form of mathematics textbooks. (At least IMHO!)

[image]

(Of course, this depends on `\sl` being a defined font, which, while it works just fine in standard LaTeX environments, may not be the case if you're using more modern typography from something like LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX — maybe see [How do I “fake” slanted text in LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289439/how-do-i-fake-slanted-text-in-latex) on SO.)

Comment: Rather than `\textrm{\sl d}` it should be `\textnormal{\slshape d}`

Answer (score 10):

As of 2022, a new package [fixdif](https://ctan.org/pkg/fixdif) has been released on CTAN with the express purpose of 'correctly' typesetting differential operators. The package must be loaded after `unicode-math` and `hyperref` if they are used. Add the `[normal]` option while loading the package to get italic d. There are other options available as well for typesetting partial and lowercase delta.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontsetup}
\usepackage{fixdif}          
\letdif*{\del}{updelta}
\newdif*{\D}{\mathrm{D}}
\newdif*{\pr}{\symup{\partial}}
\begin{document}
    \[\d x \D x \pr x \del x\]
\end{document}
```

The above code will compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, although the package can be used with pdfLaTeX as well.

[image]

Comment: Please, replace `\gdef\d{\relax\ifmmode\@dif\else\expandafter\d@accent\fi}` with `\DeclareRobustCommand\d{\ifmmode\@dif\else\expandafter\d@accent\fi}`.

Comment: @egreg I am not an expert in LaTeX and do not understand what this replacement does. Can you please explain? I can forward your message to the package maintainer so that he can make the changes in the code.

Comment: See https://github.com/AlphaZTX/fixdif/issues/2

Answer (score 8):

Just as a complement: nobody seems to have mentioned `derivative`, a package based on `expl3`. Ever since I noticed it last year, I've been using its commands to typeset differentials. The key-value interface makes it quite remarkable:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This package looks really useful. Those who desire upright lowercase deltas and upright partials can insert the following in the preamble. `\DeclareDifferential{\fdif}{\symup{\delta}}
\DeclareDifferential{\pdif}{\symup{\partial}}[style-notation=single,
style-notation-*=mixed]
\DeclareDerivative{\fdv}{\symup{\delta}}
\DeclareDerivative{\jdv}{\symup{\partial}}[fun=true, var=1]`

Answer (score 8):

I think [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88961/52406) is straight to the point, the most important thing is to *be consistent*. Standards will vary from field to field (and from author to author).

I want to add what I believe is the correct solution when it comes to the typesetting of differentials and derivatives in TeX. *This is a ConTeXt answer; currently the method is only available there*.

In winter 2021/2022 Hans opened up the math typesetting by the possibility to add more math atom classes in luametatex. Some new classes were added in the engine, some other in ConTeXt.

The differential class belongs to the second family, and it is set up to give (what we believe is) the correct spacing when combined with the other classes (ord, bin, rel, and so on). More or less what you would get by inserting `\,`, a thin space.

One could discuss what characters should belong to a differential class. In ConTeXt these do: 0x2145 (doublestruck differential D), 0x2146 (doublestruck differential d), 0x2202 (partial). One could argue that the first two of them look bad and should not be used (and one could argue if they should have been added at all, but that is another story).

In any case, the macro `\dd` is defined to give an italic d of differential class. With a new version of ConTeXt one can use

```
\setupmathematics[differentiald=upright]
```

to change the `\dd` to upright. Let us look at an example, with the formulas from the question.

```
\starttext

\showmakeup[mathglue]

\startbuffer
\startTEXpage[offset=1dk]
\im{ L\dd x^2+2M\dd x\dd y + N\dd y^2 }\par
\dm{ \frac{\dd y}{\dd x} }\par
\dm{ \int_a^b f(x) \dd x }
\stopTEXpage
\stopbuffer

\getbuffer

\setupmathematics[differentiald=upright]

\getbuffer
\stoptext
```

The result is:

[image: image with two pages, one with italic d and one with upright]

Some remarks:

The `\showmakeup[mathglue]` is there to show what spaces are inserted. We see for example that between the first L and the \dd there is an `orddif` (ordinary-differential) inserted.

Currently, the differential class is set up to have the same inter atom spaces as the ordinary class, with a few exceptions:

```
\inherited\setmathspacing \mathclosecode       \mathdifferentialcode \allsplitstyles  \thinmuskip
\inherited\setmathspacing \mathclosecode       \mathdifferentialcode \allscriptstyles \tinymuskip
\inherited\setmathspacing \mathordinarycode    \mathdifferentialcode \allsplitstyles  \thinmuskip
\inherited\setmathspacing \mathordinarycode    \mathdifferentialcode \allscriptstyles \tinymuskip
```

This means that between close and differential there should be a `\thinmuskip` (or a `\tinymuskip` if we are in sub/superscript). The same between ordinary and differential.

(The `\im` is inline math and `\dm` is display math.)

Comment: A fact relevant to the original TeX:  Knuth, following the US tradition using the italic *d*, assigned no italic correction to *d* in `cmmi10.tfm`, unlike all other letters, where this feature is responsible for the separation of a letter from what follows it.  Other fonts do assign an italic correction to *d*; the practice is inconsistent.

Answer (score 5):

#### Math is not a programming language

Unlike programming languages, mathematics is a flexible and contextual language so you may freely define your notation however you please, so long as you are **transparent** and **consistent**.

Of course [a group of people](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf) would gather to standardize such notations to facilitate communication. And if following such standards reduces the beauty of your equations and makes you go against the most common convention (e.g. the majority of Wikipedia, most publications, most websites, and textbooks such as Stewart Calculus), feel free to make your own mind.

##### Notation guidelines

This is the rational for *my* typographical and notation preferences on writing differentials:

- With the exception of introductory educational contexts, I avoid Leibniz's  *df / dx* notation because it is an abuse of notation. It wrongfully implies that differentiation is a ratio of two infinitesimal differentials (for instance see [this](https://www.expii.com/t/differential-dy-notation-and-intuition-179) or [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form)). Firstly, it is not a ratio. Secondly, despite the misconception, mathematicians have established that *df* or *dx* differentials are not infinitesimal (for integration we force them to be infinitesimal by taking a limit). So, I define my differential operator as ∂_x since I'm not a big fan of *D_x*.
- Defining commands enhances readability and changeability.
- These are LaTex operators and it is easier to programmatically generate or parse them, if needed.
- Pay attention to `\,` space and don't use it after `+`.
- If you prefer the upright version, feel free to add a `\mathrm` in the commands.

#### Sample code

```latex
$$
\newcommand{\d}{\mathop{}\!{d}}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathop{}\!{\partial}}

\p{x_2} \p{x_2} \p{x_1} {f(x_1, x_2)} = \p_{x_2}^{2} \p_{x_1} {f} = \p_{2}^{2} \p_{1} {f}

\\

\d{f(t, x)} = \p_t{f} \, \d{t} + \p_x{f} \, \d{x} + \frac{1}{2} \, \p_x^2{f} \, \d{x^2} + \dots

\\

\int f(x) \, \d{x}
$$
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to reconcile your response with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523272/195752). In the last line of your sample code, should `\int f(x) \, \d{x}` be `\int f(x) \d{x}` to avoid the extra thin space?

Comment: How do you differentiate between partial derivatives and total derivatives? Or do you think that we should abolish the concept of a total derivative? Total derivatives, e.g. `d/dt f(x, y)`, are more clearly expressible in terms of partial derivatives anyways, e.g. `/t f(x(t), y(t)) = f/x x/t + f/y y/t`, or equivalently in your preferred notation, `_t f(x(t), y(t)) = _x f _t x + _y f _t y`.

Comment: "*mathematics is a flexible language*": Flexibility has nothing to do here, flexibility means a single solution solving different cases. Here there is a single case and redundant solutions. The area of differential calculus is a good example of redundant conventions, different mathematicians invented different conventions for the same concept, they were never merged into a standardized one, so we have to deal with all of the confusing variants.

Answer (score 3):

I realized non of the existing answers mentioned the historical, before TeX aspects of typesetting mathematics, and I would like dispel the (possible) misconception that it is because Knuth and early TeX/LaTeX users are too lazy to switch a font causes the italicized `dx` to be widely used, or even to the false conclusion that there was no established typesetting convention before TeX.

At least I would like try to prove that is wasn't the arbitrary decision made my Knuth cause the widespread of italicized `dx`.

The [answer posted by Max](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88961/246082) mentioned the different typesetting convention outside US, and points out the difference.

The earliest reference material on typesetting I can find that gives example on how to typeset `dx`, is from *Modern Methods of Book Composition* printed at year 1904, written by [Theodore Low De Vinne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Low_De_Vinne), his works has been referenced a lot by Knuth.
[image]
Apparently he used italicized `dx`, while right below the paragraph shown above he emphasized sin, log, cos, tang (yes tang) should be set in roman font. Incidentally he also referenced a book *Katechismus der Buchdruckerkunst*, which sets `dx` in upright font.

So, does the font choice of `dx` seem to be arbitrary? My answer is NO.

I'm not sure if I find the exact same book of *Katechismus der Buchdruckerkunst*, but googling that title does reveals to me how an algebra book in German was typeset: https://repozytorium.biblos.pk.edu.pl/redo/resources/40573/file/scans/DEFAULT/OCR_rezultaty/100000296200_A_v1_200dpi_q60.pdf

[image]

As @barbarabeeton points out in the comment "all the math uses upright Latin letters, while the prose is Fraktur".
I think it is ok to conclude the reason behind choosing italicized or upright roman is motivated by distinguishing the formula from the text, to enhance the readability. (Also note that there is a thing space between `d x`. Seems in German books they use a thin space to indicate multiplication.)

Later is was well established for `dx` to be typeset in italicized in English, indicated by typesetting guide books such as *The Printing of Mathematics*, 1954.

And if we trace to when the `dx` notation was invented, according to [this article](https://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html), since lots of the manuscripts are published and typeset during a much later time, the earliest printed article that I can find among those is *Nouvelle méthode pour résoudre les équations littérales par le moyen des séries* (the year it printed was 1869, indicated by roman number M DCCC LXIX). Guess what?

[image]

Some may say that Hamilton’s *Lectures on Quaternions* is printed earlier (1853), and the book uses upright `d` almost everywhere. However, Hamilton explicated reserved upright `d` for differential defined for quaternion numbers rather than differential *in typical sense*, and he did used the italicized `d` once in that book on page 610, when he did mean to refer differential of a function.

Leibniz's *Nova Methodus pro Maximis et Minimis* was set in movable type and published at 1684, unfortunately, lacking lots of math symbols that were only available in movable type at much later time, all the formulas were typeset in the same roman font as the prose and symbols are drawn by hand.

Some of the old conventions were limited by the available sorts in hand composition, and that possible fact that kerning a single upright `d` with italicized `x` looks bad, but apparently there is nothing wrong to continue using italicized `dx` especially when it is not enforced! Actually, it is more precisely "using that same font for variables for `d` and put no spaces in-between", since in Concrete Mathematics for example, the font used for variables is "up-right" (but the handwriting style still distinguishes the slab text font well).

Comment: Regarding the German excerpt, observe that all the math uses *upright* Latin letters, while the prose is Fraktur.  Thank you for the explicit references. Another manual that shows the italic *d* is the Almqvist & Wiksells sättningsregler (Swedish).  I'm trying to research this topic in enough detail to write an essay for publication.  The ISO standard was written by engineers, not mathematicians.  (I've been a member of an ISO working group on document composition, so I know this for certain.)  Feel free to ping me in the chat if you're willing to discuss this.

Answer (score 1):

When a community has set its rules, its members usually don't want to appear non standard or ignorant, they often take no risk and adhere to the conventions used. Unfortunately for the differential operator the convention varies across communities.

If you want to use a global norm which reflects a consensus of different communities, ISO has standardized the practice in the field of sciences in [ISO 80000-2 Quantities and units, Part 2: Mathematics](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/en/#iso:std:iso:80000:-2:ed-2:v2:en), (superseding ISO 31/XI). It says the differential operator is a well-defined operator, and for this reason it should be typeset in roman style (regardless of where it appears):

> [image]

Convention at work in the same document:

> [image]

Used in [Mathematical Nomenclature](https://elmag.fel.cvut.cz/sites/default/files/users/capek/presentation/capek_Math_nomenclature.pdf):

> [image]

---

There are good articles summarizing this norm which is the one used in [The Princeton Companion to Applied Mathematics](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691150390/the-princeton-companion-to-applied-mathematics). An article about it: [Typesetting Mathematics According to the ISO Standard](https://nhigham.com/2016/01/28/typesetting-mathematics-according-to-the-iso-standard/).

Mathematicians [seem to agree with ISO 8000-2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4673636/874001).