# How does TeX decide how to size a middle delimiter?

Tags: math-operators, delimiters

How does TeX decide how to size a middle delimiter? When I want to show evaluation of limits of an integral, I would type `$$\int_1^2 x\; dx=\frac{x^2}{2}|_1^2=4-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{2}.$$`  How do I get the vertical bar showing the limits big enough?  I have found `\bigg` and `\Big` but I would like it to autosize like `\left`.  It seems harder because there isn't a left side to figure out what is inside.  I tried `\left` space and `\right \mid`, but didn't find success.  On math.stackexchange it was stated I just needed `\left`. as period is a delimiter.  Is there a list of delimiters?

Comment: My post doesn't get rendered by MathJax as it does on math.stackexchange.com  What should I do, as the question is difficult to read without it?

Comment: This is discussed in [Evaluation of Differentiation and Integration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15894/evaluation-of-differentiation-and-integration)

Comment: This site does not use MathJax - as we prefer to see the code. However, users are asked to provide a MWE (minimum working example) for the convenience of people that answer and to clarify and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use:

```
\[\int_1^2 x\; dx=\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_1^2=4-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{2}.\]
```

Latex grabs the height of whatever is in between the `\left` and `\right` and then adjust the delimiters (`.` and `|` in this case) to be big enough to encompass that.

Since in your example, the limit evaluation only relates to the fraction in front of it, therefore one can use `\left` and `\right` without the need of `\middle`. Since we don't need a left delimited we use `.` which stands for ''nothing''. Even if we don't want a left delimiter `\left` has to be there to tell latex where to start measuring the height.

`\middle` is only needed when three or more delimiters are used, as is the case in this example:

```
\[A = \left\{ \frac{x_i}{i} \middle| i\in \mathcal{I} \right\} \]
```

where we would want the collections curly braces to match with the inner line.

Giving a list of delimiters would be hard, since there are so many of them, and a lot of packages introduce new ones. Have a look at [The Comprehensive Symbol List](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) to have an idea of what is generally in use. I mostly use `( )` `\{  \}` `[ ]` and `|`.

Some other notes:

- I tend not to use `\Big` etc since this doesn't work automatically.
- You should use `\[` and `\]` to denote a math environment instead of `$$`, which is old tex code instead of latex.
- Have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15894/evaluation-of-differentiation-and-integration) about integral evaluation.
- When I say ''delimiters'', I don't mean that this is a class of latex symbols that is special in any way, I just mean symbols that can be scaled.

Comment: "I don't that this is a class of latex symbols that is special in any way" is confusing. What do you mean? Delimiters are an integral part of TeX. In particular, delimiters have specific `\mathcode`s.

Comment: Concerning `\Big` etc., one needs them in two places: first, when putting resized delimiters around a multiline equation; and second, when putting large parentheses around an expression that is not large enough for `\left...\right` to resize for.  This comes up when you want to set off a grouping in an expression with lots of parentheses.

Comment: `\Big` etc are also useful when the subexpression contains `\sum` or `\prod`. In those cases, `\left` and `\right` are too big. The `nath` package fixes the behavior of `\left` and `\right`; but, it is incompatible with `amsmath`.

Comment: @ TH I just meant that Ross shouldn't think delimiter are mafically special. They don't *do* much.

Comment: Be aware that in `=\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right|_1^2`, there's an extra 1.2pt of space between the = sign and the fraction than there is in `=\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg|_1^2` or, indeed, in `=\frac{x^2}{2}`. 1.2pt is the default value of `\nulldelimiterspace`, which is the actual space created by a  `\left.` or a `\right.`. (They aren't just markers; they're empty boxes with width `\nulldelimiterspace`.)