# How to automatically scale `\mid` within delimiters

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, delimiters, height

`\mid` within `\left` and `\right` delimiters is expected to be automatically scaled, but today I noticed such behavior:

```
L = \sup \left\{ \sum_{x \in F} a(x) \mid F \subset X,\, |F| < \infty \right\},
```

[image]

I suppose the optimal middle bar should be somewhat taller. (Or is this just an illusion?) Any ideas? Thanks.

BTW, this behavior was triggered in `amsart`. I didn't test it in other document classes (nevertheless, I believe that the behavior should be the same as long as `\mid` is defined).

Comment: See [How does TeX decide how to size a middle delimiter?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20785/5764). You should use `\middle` as the delimiter-sizing macro. More specifically, `\middle|`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks, I used the wrong command. Anyway, `\middle|` yields terrible result in this case, I would well go with `\mid`...

Comment: Add some spacing around it: `\,\middle|\,`. It looks terrible, but it is correct in terms of the `\left` and `\right` braces. Correct in the sense that it matches the height of the outer elements. Inside, of course, there's nothing as big close to it, so it looks excessively ugly. Suggestions would be to not use `\left` and `\right`, but rather `\bigl` and `\bigr` say, and perhaps stick to `\mid`.

Comment: For visual examples of `\bigr`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15894/evaluation-of-differentiation-and-integration

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here are some possible choices

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\begin{document}
\[
L = \sup \mleft\{\, \sum_{x \in F} a(x) \;\middle|\; F \subset X,\, |F| < \infty \,\mright\},
\]
\[
L = \sup \biggl\{\, \sum_{x \in F} a(x) \mathrel{\bigg|} F \subset X,\, |F| < \infty \,\biggr\},
\]
\[
L = \sup \biggl\{\, \sum_{x \in F} a(x) \mathrel{\Big|} F \subset X,\, |F| < \infty \,\biggr\},
\]
\end{document}
```

I'd choose the third one, probably, ruling out the first which has too high braces.

[image]