# Resize vertical bars (absolute-value symbols)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I tried that `\middle`, `\,\middle|\,` and `\mathrel{\Big|}`. I read [How to automatically scale `\mid` within delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108388/how-to-automatically-scale-mid-within-delimiters) and

```
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
MASE = \frac{1}{n} \mathrel{\Big|} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \hat{\Sigma}^{-1/2}\begin{pmatrix}
y_{ci} - \hat{y}_{ci}\\
y_{ri} - \hat{y}_{ri}
\end{pmatrix} \mathrel{\Big|},
\label{eq:mase}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you want the absolute value:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathit{MASE} = \frac{1}{n}
\left|
  \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \hat{\Sigma}^{-1/2}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    y_{ci} - \hat{y}_{ci}\\
    y_{ri} - \hat{y}_{ri}
  \end{pmatrix}
\right|,
\label{eq:mase}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've often seen `\mid` misused as vertical bar; it indeed typesets a vertical bar, but considered as a binary relation.

For the absolute value you should use `\lvert` and `\rvert`, which can be abbreviated as `\left|` and `\right|` when automatic sizing is desired.

Comment: Great answer!! "`\mid` is considered as a binary relation" ok, for example `$2\mid 5$`, but would you include it on for example `$f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)=x+5$`? Or would you go for "such that" (text)?

Comment: @manooooh I'd use two formulas: `The function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x+5$.`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that employs the macro `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` (provided by the `mathtools` package) to generate absolute-value "fences" around the summation. I would use `\abs[bigg]` rather than `\abs*`, to keep the vertical bars from becoming needlessly large. I would also write `\widehat{\Sigma}` rather than `\hat{\Sigma}`, to make the "hat" symbol a bit easier to spot. And, do write either `\mathrm{MASE}` or `\mathit{MASE}`, to inform TeX that it's dealing with an entire word rather than a product of the variables named `M`, `A`, `S`, and `E`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:mase}
\mathrm{MASE} = \frac{1}{n} 
\abs[\bigg]{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \widehat{\Sigma}^{-1/2}
\begin{pmatrix}
  y_{ci} - \hat{y}_{ci}\\
  y_{ri} - \hat{y}_{ri}
\end{pmatrix} }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```