# How do I make the symbol | larger like other delimiters?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, size

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
E(X) = \delta \left[ \frac{1}{-\delta} x e^{-\delta x} \left| \right|_0^\infty \ldots  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

It produces the following, which looks odd:

[image]

Reversing the order of the middle `\left|` and `\right|` solves the problem, but only partially (note the differently-sized final delimiter):

```
\[
E(X) = \delta \left[ \frac{1}{-\delta} x e^{-\delta x}  \right|_0^\infty \left| \ldots  \right]
\]
```

[image]

Why is that? Is there an appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does TeX decide how to size a middle delimiter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20785/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-off formula you need nothing special, just use `\Bigl` and friends.

For several appearances,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\brackeval}{O{}mmmm}
 {% #1 = size instruction
  % #2 = before the evaluation bar
  % #3 = lower bound
  % #4 = upper bound
  % #5 = after the evaluation bar
  \tonyk_brackeval:nnnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tonyk_brackeval:nnnnn
 {
  \tl_use:c { c__tonyk_brackeval_open_#1_tl } [
  #2 \vphantom{#5}
  \tl_use:c { c__tonyk_brackeval_middle_#1_tl } |\sb{#3}\sp{#4}
  \;
  #5 \vphantom{#2}
  \tl_use:c { c__tonyk_brackeval_close_#1_tl } ]
 }

% case of no optional argument
\tl_const:cn { c__tonyk_brackeval_open__tl } { }
\tl_const:cn { c__tonyk_brackeval_middle__tl } { }
\tl_const:cn { c__tonyk_brackeval_close__tl } { }
% case of *
\tl_const:cn { c__tonyk_brackeval_open_*_tl } { \mleft.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\mleft }
\tl_const:cn { c__tonyk_brackeval_middle_*_tl } { \mright }
\tl_const:cn { c__tonyk_brackeval_close_*_tl } { \mright }
% other cases
\clist_map_inline:nn { big, Big, bigg, Bigg }
 {
  \tl_const:cx { c__tonyk_brackeval_open_#1_tl } { \exp_not:c { #1l } }
  \tl_const:cx { c__tonyk_brackeval_middle_#1_tl } { \exp_not:c { #1 } }
  \tl_const:cx { c__tonyk_brackeval_close_#1_tl } { \exp_not:c { #1r } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
E(X)=\delta\brackeval{x}{a}{b}{\dots} \\
E(X)=\delta\brackeval[big]{x}{a}{b}{\dots} \\
E(X)=\delta\brackeval[Big]{-\frac{1}{\delta}xe^{-\delta x}}{0}{\infty}{\dots} \\
E(X)=\delta\brackeval[*]{-\frac{1}{\delta}xe^{-\delta x}}{0}{\infty}{\dots}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

The effect is similar to [Davislor's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/674421/4427), but it allows also automatic sizing (the syntax is slightly different, though). The trick for automatic sizing is to add a `\left.` at the beginning, so for the bar we can use `\right` that accepts limits. The sizes will be the same thanks to the phantoms.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Although you could normally use `\left[` ... `\middle|` ... `\right]` or `\left\lbrack` ... `\middle\vert` ... `\right\rbrack`, that breaks on the limits here.

So, a good alternative is `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` from `\mathtools`.  (See section 3.6 of the manual.)  This allows you to divide the inside of the expression into multiple segments and use `\delimsize` for the middle delimiter.  You call it with a size argument, such as `[\big]` or `[\bigg]`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\expect}[4]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{#1 \delimsize\vert_{#2}^{#3} #4}

\begin{document}
\[
E(X) = \delta \expect[\bigg]{\frac{1}{-\delta} x e^{-\delta x}}{0}{\infty}{\ldots}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

You’d normally be able to use a starred version of the macro to scale automatically, such as `\expect*`, but if you do that here, the limits will break.

**Eta:** And I just noticed I wrote `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` instead of `\lbrack` and `\rbrack`. Whoops!

Comment: Excellent.. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` delimiters than `\left` and `\right` to have a correct size with the whole equation.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
E(X) = \delta \Bigl[ \frac{1}{-\delta} x e^{-\delta x}  \Bigl|_0^\infty \cdots  \Bigr]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a large size  `\Biggl` and `\Biggr`:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
E(X) = \delta \Biggl[ \frac{1}{-\delta} x e^{-\delta x}  \Biggl|_0^\infty \cdots  \Biggr]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought TeX sized things correctly automatically, that was why I was surprised by the result of my first try. Good to know about \Big and \Bigr. Handy too that there is no ``matching'' required -- saves on key strokes.

Comment: To all those who responded thank you. So many amazing answers. I confess that I"m confused that I'm still getting answers because I understood this post had been deleted by Mensch and Werner. I assume I can still see it because it's my post, but I assume no one else can. Certain aspects of this Exchange leave me scratching my head.

Comment: @TonyK Don't worry. This is the LaTeX :-)