# How to put an inequality sign along with a letter as a subscript when using equations?

Tags: subscripts

First time posting, sorry if my question in the title isn't clear enough. To clarify, I'm trying to put an inequality sign, more specifically the sign `>` alongside a given Greek letter (alpha) after a given line assumption.

I want to put have something like this, which was done in Word as a draft.

[image]

Whereas in LaTeX, the outcome is like this

[image]

A sample of my work is as follows

```
FOC\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial G}{\partial q} = \mu_z - r_0 - 2\alpha q\sigma_z^2    \label{eq:1.6}
    \end{equation}\\
SOC\begin{equation}\frac{\partial^2G}{\partial q^2} | _\alpha >0 = -2\alpha\sigma_z^2 < 0   \label{eq:1.7}
    \end{equation}
From \ref{eq:1.3} solving for q yields
    \begin{align*}
\mu_z - r_0 = 2\alpha q\sigma_z^2
    \end{align*}
    \begin{equation}
q = \frac{u_z - r_0}{2\alpha\sigma_z^2}
   \end{equation}
```

Notice that the inequality doesn't go underneath with the letter, trying to overcome this but still haven't found a solution.

Comment: If a subscript (or superscript) has more than one character, you need to enclose it in braces (e.g. `|_{\alpha>0}`). Otherwise LaTeX has no way to know where the subscript ends.

Comment: Also see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15894/evaluation-of-differentiation-and-integration?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put {} around the underscript.

```
FOC
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial G}{\partial q} = \mu_z - r_0 - 2\alpha q\sigma_z^2 \label{eq:1.6}
\end{equation}
SOC
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial^2G}{\partial q^2} | _{\alpha >0} = -2\alpha\sigma_z^2 < 0\label{eq:1.7}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{eq:1.7} solving for $q$ yields
\begin{align}
 \mu_z - r_0 &= 2\alpha q\sigma_z^2\notag\\
 q &= \frac{u_z - r_0}{2\alpha\sigma_z^2}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: ... off-topic: `\left.\frac{\partial^2G}{\partial q^2}\right|_{\alpha >0}  = -2\alpha\sigma_z^2 < 0     \label{eq:1.7}` will give more nice result. By the way, your answer should have form of complete small document ...

Comment: @Zarko I'd much prefer something like `\Big|_{\alpha>0}` or `\bigg|_{\alpha>0}` rather than `\left.` and `\right|`.

Comment: for this reason I titled my comment "off-topic" ... :).  you solve issue of subscripts!