# What's the code for “evaluated at” line with separate limits?

Tags: math-mode, integral

I want the limits separated, like in the second one here:

- TOO CLOSE: `$\int_{a}^{b}$`
- RIGHT: `$\int\limits_{a}^{b}$`

How to I do the same thing with the vertical line "evaluated at"-limits?

- TOO CLOSE: `$|_{a}^{b}$` then the limits are too close; I want them
  more separated.
- RIGHT: `???`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Possible duplicate of [Evaluation of Differentiation and Integration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15894/evaluation-of-differentiation-and-integration)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the usual options are to use some `\vphantom` or just making the symbol larger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item $|_{a}^{b}$ WRONG?
 \item ${|\vphantom{\big|}}_{a}^{b}$ BETTER?
 \item $\Big|_{a}^{b}$ BETTER?
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can also work with `$\left. <some stuff> \right|_{a}^{b}$`.