# What formatting should I use on 'd' when writing an integral?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the proper way to typeset a differential operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator)

What formatting should I use on 'd' when writing an integral?

I normally use

```
$$\int_{-\infty}^{infty} e^{-x^2} \mathoperator{d}\!x = \pi$$
```

which produces

```
$\int_{-\infty}^{infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \pi$
```

Is there a better formatting for `dx`?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator

Comment: not really, perhaps \delta x, and if you are doing partial integration, then \partial x

Comment: Please let us know if the link provided by Scott resolves the issue :)

Comment: Yes, it resolves it.

Comment: Good to hear :)