# How to typeset variation of vector function?

Tags: math-mode

In variational calculus, the first variation is written as `\delta F` for some functional F. Vectors are often typeset with boldface, i.e. `\vec{x}` becomes `\mathbf{x}`. If I want to typeset the first variation of a vector, would I make the Delta bold as well?

I.e, which is "correct"? `\delta \mathbf{x}` or `\mathbf{\delta x}`?

Edit: The functional itself is scalar, but some constituents may not be.
[image: Functionals]

Comment: But a vector is not a functional no? Then it needs `\delta F[\mathbf{x}]`. Or are you considering a scalar product?

Comment: It seems to have nothing to do with (La)TeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the former to be the correct way. In essence you'd make the `\delta` a vector itself by typesetting it in bold face, which is clearly wrong. The variation constitutes more of an operator than a vector, in a similar vein with the integral or a differential for example, neither of which should be bold faced, regardless of the type of integrand. The better question in my eyes is, should you format it upright, cf. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator/88961#88961)

Comment: Good point with the upright issue.