# Shortcuts for code in latex

Tags: macros, automation

I am tired of writing `\frac{\partial something}{\partial something_else}`. Can I automate it by defining some sort of shortcut to it, so that when I write `\p(x)(y)` it will transform to `\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @egreg Thanks ) I also think that my tags are not correct, so it would be great if somebody tagged it appropriately.

Comment: With regards to (partial) derivatives, this question could be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22076/can-i-have-a-flexible-partial-derivative-macro

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\p[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}
    $ \p{x}{y} $
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 24):

The ability to define complex macros is one of the strengths of LaTeX. The traditional LaTeX way would be to use `\p{x}{y}` in the text instead of `\p(x)(y)`. If you are happy with `\p{x}{y}`, then you can just add

```
\newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
```

to your preamble. Since this new macro is requires mathmode, you may also want to wrap the macro in an `\ensuremath` so something like

```
\newcommand{\p}[2]{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}}
```

If you really want `\p(x)(y)` then you can add

```
\def\p(#1)(#2){\ensuremath{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}}
```

to your preamble. This isn't particularly robust in that something like `$\p((a+b)(a-b))(a+b)$` will break it. There are ways to make it more robust including LaTeX3, however, I would advise against using `\p(x)(y)` unless there is a good reason (especially as a beginner).

One final note is that it is probably better to use a slightly longer and more descriptive names for macros. While `\p` seems good now, in a few months it likely will not mean anything to you. Short macro names also increase the chances you might run into a name clash with some other package.

Comment: The `\def`-variant with the parentheses can break easily if the arguments uses parentheses too. Try e.g. `$\p((a+b)(a-b))(a+b)$`. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\usepackage{xparse}` and `\NewDocumentCommand{\p}{r()r()}{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}` than `$ \p((a+b)(a-b))(a+b) $` (Though, I find the usage of `()` very unnatural and I wouldn’t do it here either.)

Comment: I think it would be nice if you explained in your answer why it is a good idea to use ensuremath.

Comment: @Vivi good suggestion. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`commath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/commath) package has a lot of these handy macros already defined, like `\pd[2]{f}{x}`. I happen to use it, but it also has some nasty issues, like incorrect detection of inline vs. display math, and a conflict with TikZ over the colon character (see [Why does pdfTeX hang on this file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89467/why-does-pdftex-hang-on-this-file)).

Comment: The `\pd` macro, as you surely have noticed, *doesn't* work as expected. The problem is that `\ifinner` isn't true or false where the author of `commath` thinks it should. Thus using `commath` can cause many more problems than it solves.

Comment: I have to agree with @egreg that the package is not well-made. I don't see such inner details as he does, but I see some problem of concept that make the package bad IMHO (e.g. defining many 2- and 3-letter macros).