# How to redefine the colon-symbol with unicode-math (spacing problem)

Tags: xetex, amsmath, unicode-math

I want to change the usual role of `:` and `\colon`. Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

%\unimathsetup{colon=literal}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3A}
%\let\colon\relax
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\colon}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3A}


\begin{document}
    \newcommand\mycolon{\mathpunct{\char"003A}}
    \newcommand\myratio{\mathrel{\char"003A}}

    \( \pi:X \to Y \) (1)

    \( \pi\myratio X \to Y \) (2)

    \( \pi\colon X \to Y \) (3)

    \( \pi\mycolon X \to Y \) (4)
\end{document}
```

The first two have the same gap between $\pi$ und $X$. (3) has less space and (4) the least amount. Remember the spacing of (3). Now uncomment the lines to interchange the role of ':' and \colon. Through now (1') is now correctly set as a punctation, the spacing is equal to (4') and NOT equal to the previous space of (3). Is there a way to adjust them?

**EDIT: Solution due to egreg** (with minimal changes)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\patchcmd{\colon}{:}{\relcolon}{}{}         % Remove ':' from the definition of \colon 
\newcommand\myratio{\mathrel{\char"02236}}  % Define how the colon should look like as a ratio 
%\newcommand\myratio{\mathrel{\char"003A}}  % Use for wider space
\AtBeginDocument{
    \edef\relcolon                          % Define \recolon with current ':'
        {\mathrel{\Umathcharnum\the\Umathcodenum`:}}    
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`:                 % Make ':' math-active and redefine it to be \colon
    \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\colon
    \mathcode`:="8000
    \let\colon\myratio                      % Redefine \colon with \myratio                      
}

\begin{document}
    \( \pi:X \to Y \) (1)

    \( \pi\colon X \to Y \) (2)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `amsmath`, `\colon` is not simply a punctuation symbol, but has some spacing before it and more space after it than a punctuation symbol.

A (not very straightforward) way to (almost) interchange the meanings is

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\colon}{:}{\relcolon}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \edef\relcolon{\mathrel{\Umathcharnum\the\Umathcodenum`:}}
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`:
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\colon
  \mathcode`:="8000
}


\begin{document}

    \( \pi:X \to Y \) (1)

    \( \pi\mathpunct{\relcolon} X \to Y \) (2)

    \( \pi\relcolon X \to Y \) (3)

\end{document}
```

Case (1) is the same as `\colon`; case (2) is with `\mathpunct` to show the difference; case (3) is the colon as relation.

First of all I patch `\colon` so it has not an explicit `:` in its definition, or an infinite loop would happen. Then (at begin document), I define `\relcolon` with the current mathcode of `:` (`\edef` is necessary to get the explicit number). Finally I make `:` math active and give it the same meaning as `amsmath`'s `\colon`. The usage of `\relcolon` in it has no consequence, because it appears braced, so considered an ordinary symbol.

However, I don't think it's a good idea to change the semantics, because it limits portability.

[image]

If you really want to use `\colon` for the relation, then this modification of the above code should work:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\amsmathcolon\colon
\patchcmd{\amsmathcolon}{:}{\colon}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \edef\colon{\mathrel{\Umathcharnum\the\Umathcodenum`:}}
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`:
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\amsmathcolon
  \mathcode`:="8000
}


\begin{document}

    \( \pi:X \to Y \) (1)

    \( \pi\mathpunct{\colon} X \to Y \) (2)

    \( \pi\colon X \to Y \) (3)

\end{document}
```

---

Note that the option `colon=literal` *doesn't* do what's requested; here's an example

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colon=literal]{unicode-math}


\begin{document}

    \( \pi:X \to Y \) (1)

    \( \pi\mathpunct{\colon} X \to Y \) (2)

    \( \pi\colon X \to Y \) (3)

\end{document}
```

[image]

So `:` uses a wrong spacing and `\colon` isn't redefined.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! We just need to redefine `\colon` with a custom implementation (e.g `\mathrel{\char"02236}` ) to completely finish the interchange. (see my original post for the complete solution) Also, thanks for the warning about the change of semantics. I'm aware of the limits, but I think this is a better solution then to write every function definition with a `\colon`, because this clutters the code.

Comment: @altertoby I added a better way to interchange the meanings.

Comment: Yes, this works also but I think the `\char"02236` is more appropriate, as it really stands for the relational colon. (Also there is a slight difference between your solution and mine, at least in Minion Pro)

Comment: @altertoby I don't agree about appropriateness. Minion Pro doesn't have an accompanying math font, so I don't think that a math intensive document should use it as main font.

Comment: If I use your solution in a tikz-environment then the compilation 'ends' in a loop. Have you a solution for this problem?

Comment: @altertoby That's a know problem, because TikZ uses the colon in its syntax. I remain with my opinion that such a change in semantics is not a good idea.

Comment: If this problem is well-known, exists there also a well-known solution? ;-) And since this failure is just a result of the active colon, it would be nice if you can put your concerns regarding the semantics aside (Moreover, I'm the only one who ever sees the code)

Comment: @altertoby See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89467/why-does-pdftex-hang-on-this-file If you're able to use the answers for your problem, good. I'll waste my time with funner activities. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

See section §5.5.6 of `unicode-math` documentation:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colon=literal]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

    \( \pi:X \to Y \) (1)

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not work. It only redefines `\colon` but not `:`

Comment: It redefines both here.

Comment: Kind of, but the spacing of `:` equals the (bad) spacing of (2) in egreg's image above. This is also admitted in `unicode-math`s code, with something along 'I should steal the amsmath implementation here, it just looks better'

Comment: Sorry, no; `colon=literal` makes `:` into a punctuation symbol, which is not what `amsmath` does with `\colon`.