# "Where" notation in definition

Tags: math-mode

I need to define a rather complex operation. Hence I want to use the classical "where" definition style, i.e.

```
Foo = Bar(x,y) 
WHERE
x = Baz
y = Fob
```

My attempt so far in latex is:

```
\begin{align*}
\text{Foo} = \text{Bar}(x,y) && \mathbf{where} \\
x = \text{Baz}
\end{align*}
```

I am not really satisfied with the result, though:

- The where keyword does not really stand out from the layout
- The helper definitions are on the same level as the main definition

So instead of fiddling around with it, is there some kind of (semi-) canonical way to layout such definitions?

Comment: Is that maths you're writing? Or some code? If the latter, you should use a package for typesetting source code, such as `listings` or `minted`.

Comment: its pure math, code would be easy...

Comment: As Bernard mentioned in [his answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167389/17423), `\intertext` from `amsmath` (and `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`) seem sufficient: https://gist.github.com/9741278 (This is more or less just a simplification of the existing answer, thus this comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the `\text` macro to typeset stuff in roman font, but that's bad pratice because *semantically* incorrect:  the `\text` macro  should be reserved for typesetting phrases such as "where", "for all", "subject to", etc. within display math environments (e.g. `equation`, `align`, etc.), *not* for variables or function names. You should use the `\mathrm` macro, instead, here.

Here's how I would write your equations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\Foo{\mathrm{Foo}}
\newcommand\Barfun{\mathrm{Bar}}
\newcommand\Baz{\mathrm{Baz}}
\newcommand\Fob{\mathrm{Fob}}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{align*}
  \Foo &= \Barfun(x,y) \\
  \intertext{where}    
  x    &= \Baz         \\
  y    &= \Fob
\end{align*}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually function names with more than one letter are typeset upright. Still, if you think it's better in italics, at least, put it in `\mathit` so it has better spacing.

Comment: To your last edit, don't think of `\operatorname` as something that defines an operator, rather as something like `\mathrmwithfinespacing`.

Comment: @Manuel You're wrong: `\operatorname` ***does*** build an operator atom.

Comment: @egreg I know. I was just pointing out that I see no benefit from defining with `\mathrm` because with `\operatorname` you get “the same” but with better spacing in some cases.

Comment: @Manuel That's not what `\operatorname` is meant for; what you're suggesting is semantically incorrect.

Comment: @Manuel No, you get ***wrong*** spacing; unless, of course, you need an operator.

Comment: @egreg May be I look for different spacing, could you give me an example? And Jubobs, it's true, it's “semantically incorrect”.

Comment: @Manuel Try `$\operatorname{A}+\operatorname{B}$` and compare with `$\mathrm{A}+\mathrm{B}$`. The first is wrong, the second is correct.

Comment: @egreg You are right, that's something I wasn't aware of.

Comment: If this looks wrong to you, consider the `fleqn` document class option (available on most common derivates of the standard classes, afaik).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f &= f(x,y)\\
  \makebox[0.6em][l]{where} & \\
  x &= g(z)\\
  y &= h(z,x)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With another alignment and a smaller vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Barr}{Bar}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &  Foo   = \Barr(x,y)\\
  \shortintertext{where}
  \begin{cases}
    {} \\ {}
  \end{cases}
  \hspace{-1.1em}
  &
  \begin{array}{@{}l}
    x= Baz\\[6pt]
    y= Fob
  \end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: caveat lector: it's not important to the core layout approach, but care should be taken for `Foo`'s, `Baz`'s, and `Bar`'s kerning in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

Another option.

If the function name has more than one letter, it is usually typeset upright. If you are only using it once or twice, you can use `\operatorname{Foo}`, but if you are using it more times, may be it's worth defining a new command for them:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator\Fo{Foo}
\DeclareMathOperator\Ba{Bar}
\DeclareMathOperator\Bz{Baz}
\DeclareMathOperator\Fb{Fob}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Fo &= \Ba(x,y) \\ \intertext{where}
  x &= \Bz \\
  y &= \Fb
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

After a little discussion it was shown that `\operatorname{A}+\operatorname{B}` and `\mathrm{A}+\mathrm{B}` give different results (which I didn't know). So, my answer is not necessarily right (probably not).

I leave it here in case they are, in fact, operators.

Comment: Those are not math operators.

Comment: I don't know what I would call an [operator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95441/what-does-latex-understand-as-an-operator#comment204600_95449).

Comment: @jub0bs What TeX calls “Operator” formatting is appropriate for some notations that are not technically operators. (DEK, for example, does this in *Concrete Mathematics*.) And some math operators, like `\nabla` or `\partial`, should be typeset as `\mathord` in TeX. So it’s a slight misnomer.

Comment: @jub0bs You would not want to typeset the product of du and mass as dumass. You’d either want operator-like spacing, or to insert `\cdot` consistently.