# How to typeset statistical distributions

Tags: typography, math-operators, statistics

What is the consensus way to typeset statistical distributions? For the normal distribution I have seen all of:

```
$X\sim N(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$

$X\sim\mathrm{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$

$X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$
```

Are there any subtleties for distributions with multiple letters in their name or which use the Greek alphabet, particularly since the latter are not automatically italic in LaTeX? For instance:

```
$X\sim Exp(\lambda)$

$X\sim\Gamma(a,\, b)$
```

(My personal inclination would be for all distribution names to be upright, which is particularly convenient for the Greek-letter distributions. But this does not seem to be the norm in my sources.)

A related question is the degree of spacing which is appropriate between parameters for those distributions, like the normal, which take more than one.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I assume you want `$X\sim\mathit{Exp}(\lambda)$`, not `$X\sim Exp(\lambda)$`. The italic font you get with `$Exp$` would be correct only if each letter was a separate mathematical symbol (for instance, if they were three variables being multiplied together). Also, I don't know what the convention is, but I think that `$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$` is perfectly readable without any extra space.

Comment: MSC: thanks, that is obviously correct - if the italic font is desired in that context, it ought to be done using \mathit. On the other hand I don't think I've ever seen anybody use that! Which suggests the times I have seen e.g. Exp written in italic, it may have been from laziness rather than a conscious style choice. As for the spacing I have seen both with and without a space...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematical notation itself, not how to implement a particular notation in (La)TeX.

Comment: sometimes they get closed, sometimes they don't... Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator?rq=1

Comment: Is there a section in StackExchange where this question is not off-topic?  If it is so, it would be great to get answers to this very interesting question.