# When to use upright letters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

what are the conventions when to use upright letters in math mode?

Example:

```
    \begin{align}
     W_{mag} = \frac{1}{2}LI^2
    \end{align}
```

should the inductivity and the current be typeset in upright letters (`\mathrm`)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While this is an interesting question, it's not really about TeX, but rather about style.

Comment: @egreg Would it be better asked on Maths or Physics SE? (I don't know if this is discipline dependent or not?)

Comment: Possibly Physics.SE, if the topic is physics, but I'm not sure if they accept such questions. Anyway, a subscript should be upright if it is verbal (a word or abbreviation thereof) as opposed to a symbol.

Comment: @egreg: I am not very active on Physics.SE, but I doubt they would accept this question, since it's not about Physics itself, 'only' formatting. Of course, the index quantity should be upright if it's an abbreviation or a word, and just as usual if it's a symbol

Comment: Could Graphic Design SX be an alternative? There should be professional typesetters around that may also have experience with mathematics and physics print media.

Comment: Sometimes I am just lazy and set `\DeclareMathOperator\mag{mag}` so I can have `$W_\mag$`. (correct me if it is evil)

Comment: Quote from *Mathematics into Type*: "in mathematics it is often necessary to distinguish between functions and properties, which are printed in roman, and variables, which are printed in italic; in symbolic logic both roman and italic variable are often used.''

Comment: @Symbol1: this won't work, first `\mag` is a TEX primitive, second using  `\mathop` with subscript will give some grouping issue so you still have to type `W_{\mag}`. Might as well do `\newcommand{\mag}{\mathrm{mag}}`.

Answer (score 1):

I would typeset this as

```
\[
    W_\mathrm{mag} = \frac{1}{2} L I^2
\]
```

i.e. variables should be in standard math mode italic, while subscripts that are simply labels should be upright.

There is no correct answer for this, as it depends on the style of your region, your academic field, and personal taste. See [What's the proper way to typeset a differential operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14821/15830) for a helpful discussion of this topic.

Comment: Some tend to also make units upright - which may be helpful for e.g. distinguishing between a volume and volts or an area and amperes.