# What is really function of \mathop command?

Tags: math-mode

I'm a newbie in LaTeX. When I was reading the Tutorial book about LaTeX, I got a command

```
\newcommand {\dd}{\mathop{}\,\mathrm{d}}
```

Actually, I understand the function of that command but I don;t get the practical function of a command `\mathop{}` in this situation and in general case.

Comment: The `\mathop` will insert extra space if the `\dd` is preceded by a math atom.

Comment: Adding extra space is not the function of ``\mathop`` but of the ``\,`` command actually

Comment: I'm not sure the `\,` is even needed here. The `\mathop{}` will add the space.

Comment: The command is ill defined. It should be `\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}`. Where did you find the version with `\,`?

Comment: @egreg I think that this version is alright because if you add ``\!`` , ``dx`` will be stick with f(x) if I use ``f(x)\ddx``, it is not good at all

Comment: @HoangNam no. The code you show is wrong. Which tutorial are you using, can you give a link?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fine math typography prescribes a thin space in order to separate a function from a differential.

The `\mathop{}` bit does this, because when a `\mathop` follows an ordinary atom or a closing atom, TeX will add a thin space between them.

Such a thin space will not be added if `\mathop` is preceded by an operation symbol, like in `\dd x+\dd y`: only the automatic space surrounding `+` would be used.

The problem with the definition you found is that there is ***too much*** space: indeed, `\mathop{}` also inserts a thin space if followed by an ordinary atom (your `\mathrm{d}`), and you add another one.

You should instead ***remove*** the automatically added space.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ddbad}{\mathop{}\,\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\ddgood}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\[
\int f(x)\ddbad x \qquad \int f(x)\ddgood x
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\ddbad` you get ***three*** thin spaces, one before `\mathop{}` and two after it. With `\ddgood` there is just one thin space, because `\!` cancels out the one automatically inserted after `\mathop{}`.

If you try and typeset

```latex
\[
\ddbad x+\ddbad y \qquad \ddgood x+\ddgood y
\]
```

you'll see more clearly what goes wrong.

[image]