# How to change the font size of a particular letter

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I referred the link : [How do I change the font of a letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/how-do-i-change-the-font-of-a-letter). But the link didn't help me out. I would like to achieve this:

[image]
Here is the MWE though I know it isn't :(:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say that you shouldn't want to achieve that. The kerning between the huge ``W`` and the following ``o`` is way off, and I find this esthetically very displeasing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking into consideration the questions by the OP, and following both David's and John's answer, I'm trying to include a wider response:

If you just want to get a few letter in a bigger size than the others, you can ---as stated by the other answers--- just use `{\huge H}ello {\huge W}orkd`.

If you want to have a [Drop Cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial), you can use the [`lettrine package`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lettrine).  E.g.:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

{\huge H}ello {\huge W}orld.

This is a regular line.  Lets say you want a drop cap in the next chapter.

\chapter{Chapter Name}

\lettrine{T}{his} is a beautiful drop cap.  If you want to change the size of it, please refer to the lettrine package documentation.

\end{document}
```

Where the result is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hahahahahahahahaha

Comment: `{\huge H}ello {\huge W}\kern-0.25em orld` to fix the kerning.

Answer (score 7):

```
 {\huge H}ello {\huge W}orld
```

Or look at packages such as lettrine

[image]

Comment: +1 For recommending the [lettrine package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lettrine).  Most likely the OP is trying to achieve something related to a Drop Cap.

Comment: How to define a command such that the first letter of every first paragraph in every chapter is similar to this?

Comment: I wouldn't do that I would use lettrine (so the capital is dropped into a cut out paragraph) and mark it up in each case) to do this well almost always requires "by eye" space adjustments depending on the letter, as seen in the image in John's answer you would want to add negative space to pull the `o` closer to the `W` there is no automatic font kerns as you are changing font (even if only changing font size)

Comment: I'll write a new answer with examples :)

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick.

```
{\huge H}ello {\huge W}orld
```

[image]

Comment: 11 seconds late:-)

Comment: But mine has a picture `;)`

Comment: and a lovely picture it is

Comment: But whose is bigger?

Comment: I hereby declare this comment dialogue *'silly'.*

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\9[1]{{\Huge#1}}
\begin{document}
\9Hello \9World
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you use a `9`!?