# How to redefine the "plus" symbol?

Tags: macros, equations, symbols

Let's say I don't like the way the + symbol is printed inside equation: is there a way to change its appearance without defining a new command?

More generally, is it possible to create a command without the initial backslash?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please be a bit more specific regarding your dislike for the way the `+` symbol is printed in math mode. Is it its size, shape, height above the baseline, spacing relative to adjoining symbols, or something else entirely? Separately, which (math) font do you use?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/how-do-i-change-the-font-of-a-letter

Comment: I asked a new question on how to redefine multiple symbols. e.g. minus, plus and plusminus: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361807/how-to-change-the-font-of-math-operators-e-g-plus-and-minus

Answer (score 17):

Yes, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\catcode`+=\active
\gdef+{\mathbin{\mathrm{blurb}}}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }

\begin{document}
$x+y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can think to better definition for the “math active” `+`. `;-)`

---

A more general approach where you can also use an equivalent of the character being “redefined”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathactivedef}[3][]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#2\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#3}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \@ifdefinable{#1}{\mathchardef#1=\mathcode`#2\relax}%
  \fi
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#2="8000 }%
}
\@onlypreamble{\mathactivedef}
\makeatother

\mathactivedef[\keptplus]{+}{\mathbin{(\mkern-2mu\keptplus\mkern-2mu)}}

\begin{document}

$x+y$

\end{document}
```

In the optional argument to `\mathactivedef` you set the equivalent name that you can use in the body of the redefinition.

[image]

The previous “blurb” (without keeping the meaning of `+`) would be

```
\mathactivedef{+}{\mathbin{blurb}}
```

Comment: I understand the making `+` active part.  But can you elaborate on what the `\mathcode` does and why it must occur `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: You could have chosen something more interesting than `blurb`. How about `this\ is\ Sparta`?

Comment: Actually, I would like to know the answer to Steven’s question, too. Are you gonna answer? `;-)`

Comment: How can I use the symbol inside its redefinition? Say I want to type `+`, but in the pdf it prints as `++`.

Comment: @antshar I added a more general way that copes with your problem

Comment: @egreg I found out that `\mathchar\`+` also does the thing.

Comment: @antshar Not completely, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a really great, more general answer at
https://newbedev.com/make-characters-active-via-macro-in-math-mode
(at the bottom of the page).

Comment: The code you show comes actually from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299805/82917