# how to redefine single letter in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I'd like to use in math mode instead *the only letter* g the `\mbox{g}` (with another tail). How possible to redefine it globally? I found example to redefine letter z:

```
\catcode`\z=\active \def z{Yawn, I'm tired}
```

But it does not work for letter g! The code

```
\catcode`\g=\active \def g{\mbox{g}}
```

returns errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is a very big difference: `Yawn, I'm tired` doesn't contain `z`, whereas `\mbox{g}` contains a `g`.

Comment: But \catcode`\g=\active 
\def g{Y}% does not work!

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335/86 to see another way to do this.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Related question: [macros - How to redefine the "plus" symbol? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279772/how-to-redefine-the-plus-symbol)

Answer (score 9):

Making letters into active characters is definitely not a good idea.

For instance, after

```
\catcode`\g=\active
```

you are not allowed to use `\begin` any more.

For math mode there's a different solution:

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`g \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mbox{g}}
\mathcode`g="8000
```

This makes `g` into a *math active* character; since `\mbox` switches to text mode, the `g` will not cause problems.

---

With `` \catcode`\g=\active \def g{\mbox{g}} `` you're basically doing the same as

```
\def\foo{\mbox{\foo}}
```

which starts an infinite loop as soon as `\foo` is expanded.