# How to redefine spacing of a symbol inside a macro?

Tags: spacing

When writing mathematics expression, I would like to remove the space around the symbol `+`.

For a simple expression `a+b`, I can do it by enclosing `+` like `a{+}b`. But it requires more labor work for complex expression like: `a+b+c+d+e`.

I would like to ask whether there is a *programmable* way so that I can define a macro `fooplus`:

```
\newcommand{\fooplus}[1]{do some thing here about +}
```

so that `\fooplus{a+b+c+d+e}` produces the same result like`a{+}b{+}c{+}d{+}e`?

Thanks for spending time to take a look at my question.

Comment: Possible. But the meaning will change. Do you really want that?

Comment: One option is to define `\newcommand\p{{+}}` and then write `$a\p b\p c\p d\p e$`.

Comment: Are you using `\fooplus` inside math mode?

Comment: One way would be by changing catcode of `+`.  [Make Characters Active via Macro in Math Mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299798/4301) should get you going.  However, I would recommend you _not_ do this.  There is a reason why the binary spacing is different than the unary spacing. See the difference in `$+5+7=12$`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: it will be very useful in my opinion since we can easily enclose or remove the command `\fooplus`.

Comment: @Andrew: yeah, but then I need to revise all expressions.

Comment: @Wernner: not neccesary, but will it be easier in the math mode?

Comment: @Peter Grill: should your solution apply globally even outside the macro?___ *updated*___ Thanks for the suggestion, it may be the one close to my need

Comment: Another option (related/duplicate): [How to redefine the "plus" symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279772/5764)

Comment: @TrungTa: You can decide if you want it globally or only within a specfic macro. Both options should be doable. But, I still recommend you _not_ do this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For simple cases it's sufficient to change the math code of `+` (in a group):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\fooplus[1]{%
  \begingroup\mathcode`+=\numexpr\mathcode`+-"2000\relax
  #1
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
$\fooplus{a+b+c+d+e}\neq x+y$

$a+b+c+d+e\neq x+y$
\end{document}
```

Explanation. Since `+` should be a binary operation symbol, its mathcode is of the form `"2abc`, so subtracting `"2000` we turn it into an ordinary symbol.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tested and it works perfectly. For curiosity, I tried also to with the comma `,` and subtract "1500 but it didn't work, but also work with subtracting "1000. Do you know why it is so? (note that this is for the comma `,`)

Comment: @TrungTa The mathcode of the comma is `"6abc`; if you subtract `"1500` you get a different symbol altogether; if you subtract `"1000` you get a “closing delimiter”. Subtract `"6000`, instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand. Previously, I misunderstood the number as a spacing metrics :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LuaLaTeX, it's not too much work to set up a Lua function that changes the status of `+` -- as well as `-`, `*`, and `=` --  to math-ordinary. (Lua provides powerful and flexible string handling functions.) The LaTeX macro `\fooplus` below simply invokes the Lua function.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment and '\luastring' macro
\begin{luacode}
function fooplus ( s )
  tex.sprint (( string.gsub ( s , "[%+%-%*%=]" , "{%0}" ) ))
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\fooplus[1]{\directlua{fooplus(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}
$\fooplus{a+b+c+d+e=f-g*h}$

$a+b+c+d+e=f-g*h$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very neat. I wonder why Latex cannot do the same thing?

Comment: @TrungTa - Actually, LuaLaTeX is a *combination* of the LaTeX *format* and the LuaTeX *engine*.  LuaTeX provides, among other things, an interface -- via the `\directlua` "primitive" instruction -- to the Lua programming language. (Hence the name, I suppose.) I assume your comment refers to pdfLaTeX, which is a combination of the LaTeX format and the pdfTeX engine. pdfTeX is an older, well-established, and very robust engine, but it does lack some of the "goodies" of LuaTeX.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Indeed, I'm using pdfLaTeX. I really like the programming style of LuaTeX and may try to use it soon.