# How to find all slot numbers for a given font's math glyphs, e.g. Linux Libertine

Tags: fonts, math-operators, font-encodings, libertine, newtxmath

[How to change the font of math operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361807/how-to-change-the-font-of-math-operators-e-g-plus-and-minus) led to me wanting to find the slot numbers needed to redefine all possible math operator symbols. MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operatorsB}{TS1}{\rmdefaultB}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{operators}{43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{operatorsB}{61}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pm}{\mathbin}{operatorsB}{177}

\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}
x$=+-\pm$ +\textminus\textpm

%\fonttable{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}
%\xfonttable{TS1}{\rmdefaultB}{m}{n}
%\xfonttable{TS1}{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

In the comments, `T1enc.def` and `ts1enc.def` files were proposed for this, but looking in the files wasn't helpful for me.

The other often found suggestion is using `fonttable` package. Activating any of the three fonttable commands in my MWE gives a slew of erros, even though I just used the settings from above or the working font specifiers for my  `microtype` settings (`{TS1}{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}{m}{n}`).

Also suggested reading material was the [`fntguide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/fntguide.pdf), but I couldn't find the tables I need nor individual slot numbers (`=` for example ...).

So, how to find all possible math slot numbers of Linux Libertine (or any other font of a package) to work with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is with `standalone`, use `article`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operatorsB}{TS1}{\rmdefaultB}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{operators}{43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{operatorsB}{61}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pm}{\mathbin}{operatorsB}{177}

\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}

x$=+-\pm$ +\textminus\textpm

\xfonttable{TS1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please expand your answer with the font tables that show plus, minus, equals sign and others? Looking at the slot numbers in my MWE I can't find them in that one font table and `\pm` is at the "wrong" place (261 instead of 177). My question is mainly about how to find "all" slot numbers of a given font, as this is a problem I face often.

Comment: It *is* at 177, `261` is the octal representation. The decimal representation is in the cell itself and is 177.

Comment: I can handle converting the numbers, but where are the other symbols? This was the core of my question, I want to get all slot numbers of the common mathematical operator symbols.

Comment: @lblb There aren't. That's why most are substituted with `newtxmath` symbols.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Last question: LinLibertine still has the equals sign `=` that is not found in the table, what slot number / command is needed to use it?

Comment: @lblb That's in the normal text font, encoding T1 or OT1. I think you can use the `operators` symbol font.

Comment: @lblb ``\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{operators}{`=}``

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you get error messages is that you're not correctly specifying the font file you want to peak into.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}
\fonttable{LinLibertineT-lf-ts1}
\end{document}
```

[image]