# Redefining asterisk (*) in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, characters

I am attempting to use a symbol from a separate font for the centered asterisk (∗) math operator. The font in question only has the heightened (in many fonts) asterisk glyph (*), which I try to use for the centered variant by lowering it.

In math mode, the operator can be used both by `*` and `\ast`, who are defined in exactly the same way at lines 150 and 297 in `fontmath.ltx`.

`\ast` can be redefined with `\renewcommand`, but `*` seems to be another beast. Can it be changed into a macro, or in any other way change the baseline of the glyph?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mymathoperators}{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\protoast}{\mathbin}{mymathoperators}{"2A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{*}{\mathbin}{mymathoperators}{"2A}

\renewcommand*{\ast}{\mathbin{\raisebox{-0.7ex}{\ensuremath{\protoast}}}}

\begin{document}

\( good \ast , bad * . \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since `*` is not a letter, it cannot be used directly in a control word; here, a control word is a backslash followed by one or more letters. What you need to do  is to make `*` "active", to use some TeX jargon, and then to assign `*` a certain meaning, e.g., to make it equivalent to `{\ast}`.

Comment: Related question: [macros - How to redefine the "plus" symbol? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279772/how-to-redefine-the-plus-symbol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [@egreg's `\DeclareMathActive`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299798/make-characters-active-via-macro-in-math-mode/299804):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mymathoperators}{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\protoast}{\mathbin}{mymathoperators}{"2A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{*}{\mathbin}{mymathoperators}{"2A}

\renewcommand*{\ast}{\mathbin{\raisebox{-0.7ex}{\ensuremath{\protoast}}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
  % #1 is the character, #2 is the definition
  \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }%
}
\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
\patchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\mathcode`\-\relax}{\std@minuscode\relax}{}{\ddt}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\std@minuscode{\the\mathcode`-}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathActive{*}{\ast}

\begin{document}

\(good \ast , bad * . \)

\end{document}
```