# question about \DeclareMathActive and unbraced super/subscript

Tags: math-mode, macros, superscripts, kpfonts

I find the asterisk of `kpfonts` too small when used in super/subscripts so, following answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414922/208544) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299805/208544), I'm using @egreg's brilliant `\DeclareMathActive` to redefine `*` in math mode as `\textstyle\ast`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
  % #1 is the character, #2 is the definition
  \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }%
}

\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
\patchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\mathcode`\-\relax}{\std@minuscode\relax}{}{\ddt}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\std@minuscode{\the\mathcode`-}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathActive{*}{{\textstyle\ast}}

\begin{document}
$f_*\mathscr{F} \quad f^*\mathscr{F} \quad R^*$

$A*B$
\end{document}
```

This works wonderfully, except that in order to make `R^*` work without bracing the `*` (as in `R^{*}`), I have to add braces around `\textstyle\ast`. This then removes the `\mathbin` spacing in expressions like `A*B`.

Is there any hack to `\DeclareMathActive` that would allow for both unbraced `*` in super/subscripts and correct spacing in `A*B`? One idea is to extend `DeclareMathActive` to take arguments like `\mathchoice`:

```
\DeclareMathActiveChoice{<char>}{<display code>}{<text code>}{<script code>}{<scriptscript code>}
```

Then one could use `\DeclareMathActiveChoice{*}{\ast}{\ast}{{\textstyle\ast}}{\ast}`.

However I have no idea how to implement such an extension.

---

Just for context, here's why I want to do this at all. Compare

[image: ast-sizes]

And for a professionally typeset comparison, here's the same line in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*:

[image: Hartshorne]

Comment: you could make `^` math active defined by `\def^#1{\sp{#1}}`

Comment: Thanks, ``\catcode`\^=\active \def^#1{\sp{#1}}`` works. One also has to do ``\catcode`\_=\active \def_#1{\sb{#1}}``. I thought perhaps this would break `e{_}`-type args of `\NewDocumentCommand` but it seems to work fine. Is there any downside? Also feel free to post your comment as an answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems this breaks `\input{my_file}`, which I suppose is expected

Comment: not if you make it math active, that's the point, it only affects math mode

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean with something like `\ifmmode`, with `\DeclareMathActive`, or another way?

Comment: you don't need ifmmode, use mathcode "8000 or, since you have defined it \DeclareMathActive something like `\def\foohat#1{\sp{#1}}\DeclareMathActive{^}{\foohat}`  I guess

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I must be missing something because that gives me the bracing error, `Missing { inserted`

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [math mode - How to avoid using curly braces when placing a \DeclareMathOperator command in subscript or superscript, while preserving spacing? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437378/how-to-avoid-using-curly-braces-when-placing-a-declaremathoperator-command-in-s) ?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I prefer using macros for everything instead of manual syntax like `^*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `^`  and `_` grab arguments like a macro, which would mean `x^\frac{1}{2}` would no longer work, it would need  `x^{\frac{1}{2}}` but that is no great loss.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
  % #1 is the character, #2 is the definition
  \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }%
}

\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
\patchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\mathcode`\-\relax}{\std@minuscode\relax}{}{\ddt}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\std@minuscode{\the\mathcode`-}}
\@makeother\^
\@makeother\_
\makeatother

\DeclareMathActive{*}{\mathbin{\textstyle\ast}}
\DeclareMathActive{^}{\foosup}
\DeclareMathActive{_}{\foosub}
\def\foosup#1{\sp{#1}}
\def\foosub#1{\sb{#1}}

\begin{document}
$f_*\mathscr{F} \quad f^*\mathscr{F} \quad R^*$

$A*B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a special place in Hell for people who type `x^\frac{1}{2}`.

Comment: @Gaussler they can claim redemption by using `x^\frac12`

Comment: For those, there is an even more special place, much deeper down in Hell.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you this is great. Why do auxiliary commands `\foosup` have to be defined? `\DeclareMathActive{^}{\sp}` does not work but I don't know why

Comment: @mbert `\DeclareMathActive{^}{\sp}` would do nothing as `\sp` is `^` you need a macro taking `#1` that   is the point of the definition

Comment: I see, I misunderstood `\sp`