# How can I re-define a math operator / symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm new user and really need your help.
I want to fix the size and position of a *"math symbol"*. For example, I want to scale and adjust vertical position of symbol "+". According to information on internet, I try this way and it worked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\plus{\raisebox{0.13\height}{\scalebox{0.95}{$\mspace{4mu}+\mspace{4mu}$}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$1+2+3\\
1\plus 2\plus 3$
\end{document}
```

[image: *enter image description here*]

However, I wonder that how I can re-define the symbol "+" directly in the system without using syntax <\plus>.

I try to find more information, it leads me to "catcode". But I cannot apply it because of no knowledge about the syntax and structure.

Comment: note that the entire math setting is based on a "math axis" so - a fraction bar, and all operators such as < and > are all aligned on the same vertical position as the horizontal bar of the + so if you move that things will look unaligned.

Comment: See also: [macros - How to redefine the "plus" symbol? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279772/how-to-redefine-the-plus-symbol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do as follows, making `+` math active.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoplus}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@plus}[2]{%
  \raisebox{0.13\height}{\scalebox{0.95}{$\m@th#1\standardplus$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$1+2+3_{a+b}$ (modified)

$1\standardplus 2\standardplus 3_{a\standardplus b}$ (original)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much!

Comment: excuse me, but how we can deal with other operator, like \times, etc.
I cannot use similar syntax : \mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`\times

Comment: @Tauyeco You should first think deeply about modifying that way standard symbols: there are several reasons why they're shaped and positioned the way they are.

Comment: .@egreg: I know about the standard. But because of changing of math font, sometimes there are some symbols which don't have correct view. I just want to fix some small issues like above without changing so much. It's better if I can understand deeply, but currently I just have a little bit time.

Another question is, how I can know the list of all mathcode of symbol?