# Specifying font for a special glyph

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols

Is it possible to set a font for a glyph without adding markup around each occurrence of the glyph? e.g. my current font does not support angle bracket (`〈 〉`).

Comment: Do you want to use the angle bracket within math mode? `\langle \rangle`?

Comment: @Sigur No, in text mode. In math mode it works correctly using unicode-math

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335/can-i-change-the-font-and-colour-of-a-letter-permanently?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `newunicodechar` package. (Also works with `xelatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{〈}{\ensuremath{\langle}}
\newunicodechar{〉}{\ensuremath{\rangle}}
\begin{document}
Here are angle〈 〉brackets.

$Here are angle〈 〉brackets.$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This is one of the cases where `\ensuremath` can be useful.

Comment: @egreg Indeed. This is the first time, that `\ensuremath` comes in handy to me.